# Is this the right way to clean-up Fragment back stack when leaving a deeply nested stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I'm using the Android Compatibility library to implement fragments and have extended the layout sample so that a fragment contains a button which fires off another fragment.

In the selection pane on the left I have 5 selectable items - `A B C D E`.

Each loads up a fragment (via `FragmentTransaction:replace`) in the details pane - `a b c d e`

Now I've extended fragment `e` to contain a button which loads up another fragment `e1` also in the details pane. I've done this on fragment `e`'s onClick method as follows:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.details_frag, newFrag);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

If I make the following selections:

```
E - e - e1 - D - E
```

Then fragment `e` is in the details pane. This is fine and what I want. However, if I hit the `back` button at this point it does nothing. I have to click it twice because `e1` is still on the stack. Furthermore after clicking around I got a null pointer exception in onCreateView:

To 'solve' this problem I added the following whenever `A B C D E` is selected:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

Just wondering whether this is the correct solution or whether I should be doing something different?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Well there are a few ways to go about this depending on the intended behavior, but this link should give you all the best solutions and not surprisingly is from Dianne Hackborn

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d2a5c203dad6ec42

Essentially you have the following options

- Use a name for your initial back stack state and use
  `FragmentManager.popBackStack(String name,
  FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)`.
- Use `FragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()`/`getBackStackEntryAt().getId()`
  to retrieve the ID of the first entry on the back stack, and
  `FragmentManager.popBackStack(int id,
  FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)`.
- `FragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)`
  is supposed to pop the entire back stack...  I think the documentation for
  that is just wrong.  (Actually I guess it just doesn't cover the case where
  you pass in `POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE`),

Comment: What does this mean?

FragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()/getBackStackEntryAt().getId()

Comment: 2nd worked for me. What it means for clearing the entire stack: getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId(),
                        FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: @JorgeGarcia is it possible after popbackstack we just finish our fragment without restart older one.

Comment: Please note there is also the popBackStackImmediate() version since popBackStack() is async, meaning the clearing up does not occur at the exact moment you call the method.

Comment: Claims the group is banned as spam and i cannot access the link :( does anyone have the resource elsewhere?

Comment: What if I have multiple fragments in flow like A-->B--->C-->D and from D if I want to go back to C and then to B and at last to A. But Above options always land me to A if I clicked back on B/C/D. What should be the proper way to manage this?

Comment: @NGR, simply `FragmentManager.popBackStack()` at every step.

Answer (score 62):

The other clean solution if you don't want to pop all stack entries...

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_activity_container, fragmentInstance).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

This will clean the stack first and then load a new fragment, so at any given point you'll have only single fragment in stack

Comment: This is very bad: `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);` before a replace() because are loading the Fragment calling `onCreateView()`, `onActivityCreated()`, etc. Restoring and Destroing a Fragment instantly is bad. The Fragment can register a receiver for example. This affects the performance.

Comment: @VasileM, could you describe in details? In what cases it is bad? Is it because of asynhronous behaviour of `FragmentTransaction`? Is there only bad performance of wrong fragment stack?

Comment: @VasileM for that it could be a good practice to register observer and other jobs in OnViewCreated Fragment flow callback, or handle unregisering observers when the currently fragment is destroyed  '    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        viewModel.viewState.removeObservers(this)
        
    }
'

Answer (score 28):

Thanks to [Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751429/joachim) answer, I use the code to clear all back stack entry finally.

```
// In your FragmentActivity use getSupprotFragmentManager() to get the FragmentManager.

// Clear all back stack.
int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
for (int i = 0; i < backStackCount; i++) {

    // Get the back stack fragment id.
    int backStackId = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId();

    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(backStackId, 
        FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

} /* end of for */
```

Comment: Why do use a loop here? For me FragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE) cleared all back stack entry...

Comment: @Marek, because sometimes not all fragments should be removed, a loop is suitable for this.

Comment: @CoolMind, that still doesn't make sense to me. `popBackStack(backStackId, INCLUSIVE)` will pop all the fragments (states) back to backStackId, so once you pop the lowest `i` that you're going to pop, all the higher ones should get popped at the same time. So what's the point of a loop?

Comment: @LarsH, you are right. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59158254/2914140. In order to pop other fragments to required tag, we should first add the fragment with addToBackStack(**tag**).

Answer (score 7):

I have researched a lot for cleaning Backstack, and finally see [Transaction BackStack and its management](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/09/19/transaction-backstack-and-its-management/). Here is the solution that worked best for me.

```
 // CLEAR BACK STACK.
    private void clearBackStack() {
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        while (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    }
```

The above method loops over all the transactions in the backstack and removes them immediately one at a time.

**Note:** above code sometime not work and i face [ANR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540076/is-anr-an-exception-or-an-error-or-what) because of this code,so please do not try this.

**Update**
below method remove all fregment of that "name" from backstack.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.popBackStack("name",FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

- name If non-null, this is the name of a previous back state
  to look for; if found, all states up to that state will be popped.  The
- POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE flag can be used to control whether the named state itself is popped. If null, only the top state is popped.

Comment: I don't see why you would remove them one at a time. Is there a reason why you chose for this solution instead of the other solutions? Is there a reason to remove them one at a time instead of all at once?

Comment: thair no method to remove backstack at one time see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a similar code as those that use the while loop but I call the entry count in every loop... so I suppose it's somewhat slower

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
while (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        manager.popBackStackImmediate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in [How to pop fragment off backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971780/how-to-pop-fragment-off-backstack) and by [LarsH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13304102/2914140) here, we can pop several fragments from top down to specifical tag (*together with the tagged fragment*) using this method:

```
fragmentManager?.popBackStack ("frag", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Substitute "frag" with your fragment's tag. Remember that first we should add the fragment to backstack with:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("frag")
```

If we add fragments with `addToBackStack(null)`, we won't pop fragments that way.

Answer (score -4):

```
    // pop back stack all the way
    final FragmentManager fm = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    int entryCount = fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); 
    while (entryCount-- > 0) {
        fm.popBackStack();
    }
```