# Clear fragment back stack programmatic

Tags: android, fragment

What is the best way to clear fragment back stack programmatic?

I've implemented screen navigation using only one activity and set of fragments. I would like to have method that brings user to the login screen(when logout timeout expires) and clears all fragment history, what is the best way to do that? I found few answers here yet I've dont know which is the best one...Thanks in advance!

for the moment I'm using this one

```
public void clearBackStack() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = holder.getSupportFragmentManager();

    while (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, 0);
    }
}
```

Yet sometimes I'm getting outOfMemoryException

Comment: Did you check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186433/clear-back-stack-using-fragments)

Comment: I've tried similar one, or maybe I'm wrong... updated my questions

Comment: No, All resources are pretty small and predefined in res.

Comment: I've tried you solution for the moment I'm not getting any exceptions. Yet I can't verify difference betweens mines and yours code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 13):

This is a pretty old question at this point.  Anyway I tried your code and it looks like you've got an infinite loop.

`popBackStack(null, 0)` searches for a fragment with a null tag, which will never be found. The while loop will cycle until memory runs out. The other issue with `popBackStack` is that the pop is not necessarily immediately performed so the while loop could run for a while.

If you want to remove fragments from the back stack irrespective of tag or ID, use `fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FragmentManager.popBackStack()` to clear the backstack.

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

This will empty the stack without loading into the container.