# Memory leak in Android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks

My app has got a lot of fragments. When I run it in android 5.1.1 it consumes 100-200 Mb, whereas in android studio it shows 30-40 Mb. The problem is that fragments does not get destroyed when i move between them. Is there any way to force close old fragments when I open new ones?  I have tried to change behaviour of fragments in onPause and onStop methods, but it was useless

Comment: You can clear the backstack, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6198068/794088

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the number of fragments you have. If you have many fragments, you should use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html), which means a fragment will be destroyed once you move to another fragment. If you don't have that many fragments, you could simply use FragmentPagerAdapter, which keeps your fragments in memory.