# How to clear fragmentManager back stack without poping fragments?

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack, fragmentmanager

Simple question but seems impossible to answer...
How to clear fragmentManager back stack without poping fragments?

I understand it like this:

Back stack entries = list of previosly saved transactions with addToBackStack command.
For example: "replace Fragment 1 with Fragment 2".

popBackStack = do last saved transatcion reverse.
For example: "replace Fragment 2 with Fragment 1".

Let's say i did first transaction: F1->F2 and added this transaction to back stack. When I press back button now the F2->F1 will happen.

OK...But..

I've changed my mind and I want to clear the back stack.
I want the user to work with F2 fragment but when he/she presses back button the Activity should close like the back stack is empty.

I need something like:

```
for(int i=0;i<getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();i++){
    getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).remove();
}
```

**EDITED**
I've tried to ask simple question to complex situation and I get simple answer ;) 
Abhishek Patel's answer is very good but it is not what I was looking for. Still it's a good answer.

**Just to clarify:**
Back stack in android is not fully editable list like:

- transaction 1
- transaction 2
- transaction 3
- transaction 4

*We **can't** do "Remove transaction 3" to make:*

- transaction 1
- transaction 2
- transaction 4

*We **can't** clear all backstack and keep last visible fragment alive.*

*We **can** delete backstacks records to certain position like:
"Remove everything to Transaction 2" to get:*

- transaction 1
- transaction 2

On screen you'll see the efect of transaction 2.

**WHY DID I NEED THIS?**

I thought that I can make a Fragment which will be 'Main fragment'.This main fragment will use an Interface to tell whatever activity it is in that this boss fragment is shown now, and whatever happens before - is not important anymore.

(F)-Fragment, (A)-Activity

(F) - Hey dude. I'm the boss and I'm visible and attached to you. Please clear your backstack for me but keep my transaction which brought me here.

(A) - Sorry man...You should have told me before your transaction to clear my backstack so I can add your transaction on top of fresh new backstack.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186433/clear-back-stack-using-fragments

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be helpful:

```
public void clearBackStack() {
    BackStackEntry entry = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(0);
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(
            entry.getId(),
            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

}
```

Comment: I've found it before but it wasn't exactly what I was looking for. I thought backstack is like a list and i can remove whatever row I want...