# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState on clearing the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am getting the following error when I clear the backstack Fragments

```
    //clear all fragments in the back stack 
    if (getTopFragment() != null) {
        runNavAction(new NavAction("Clear nav back stack") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated..

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)
```

Comment: Can you put complete code here?

Comment: @SachinSaxena - Updated the code that gets called

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear back stack using fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186433/clear-back-stack-using-fragments)

Comment: @MaheshGiri, I am not interested to know how to clear the backstack navigations as explained in the post