# finish my acivity and back to fragment when click on back button and don't erase my data in fragment

Tags: android

I have a `mainActivity` in which I use my `fragment`. and I have two activities `Activity1` and `Activity2`. first I go to `fragment` to `Activity2`, when I click back button in `Activity2`, I need to back to `fragment` page .
it means I need to finish my `Activity2` and also finish my `Activity1` in one click. how can I get this . here is my back press code on `Activity2`.

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if(fromString.equalsIgnoreCase("Activity2")){
           this.finish();
           Activity1.finish();

        }else if(fromString.equalsIgnoreCase("Activity1"){

            finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)

        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: try this answer in your fragment https://stackoverflow.com/a/6198068/8089770

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am able to understand by your question you want to finish activity1 if you are from activity1 and both activity1 and activity2 if you are from activity2. You can achieve this by two ways :

**First way : Replace your code by this code:**

```
  @Override
```

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
// handle arrow click here
if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
    if(fromString.equalsIgnoreCase("Activity2")){           
       Activity1.finish();  // I have change the sequence of lines by that it will finish Activity1 first then Activity2 in which is residing
       this.finish();

    }else if(fromString.equalsIgnoreCase("Activity1"){

        finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)

    }
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

**Second Way :** **you can clear all your back stack activities by this code and lend to your expected Activity or fragment by this code :**

```
Intent gotoexpectIntent = new Intent(yourActivity.this,yourexpectedActivity.class);
gotoexpectIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(gotoexpectIntent );
```

Comment: and second way also tried but with this it erases my data it started as a new activity

Answer (score 0):

it's still unclear what you are asking. but to finish multiple activities on back press you can try startactivityforresult and go on from there.

Comment: my question is i want to finish activity1 when i when i go back to fragmen  from activity1 and both activity1 and activity2 when i go back to fragment  from activity2