# How to clear stack back fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem with clean my stack back.
This method shows my fragment:

```
private fun showFragment(fragment: Fragment, titleTag: String) {

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment, titleTag)
        .addToBackStack(titleTag)
        .commit()

    if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to clear my stack.

Comment: If you are using showFragment method for replacing navigation drawer items, then maybe you shoudn't put them in backstack. Because in most cases, there won't be any case to navigate back user to different drawer item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear back stack using fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186433/clear-back-stack-using-fragments)

Answer (score 3):

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```