# Is "ANR" an exception or an error or what?

Tags: android, exception, catch-block, android-anr-dialog

Is the ANR an exception, an error or what? Can we actually catch it in a `try{} catch(){}` structure?

Comment: You forgot to mention what platform you're using.

Comment: Look for "I/Choreographer(xxx): Skipped xxx frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." in your logcat. This may help you found your problem.

Comment: Looks like it's a 'what'

Answer (score 49):

**ANR** (Application Not Responding) is not exactly an error. It is shown when your application is very sluggish and takes a lot of time to respond, thus making the user wait. The user won't appreciate if your application makes them wait for a long time. So, the Android framework gives the user an option of closing your application. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

This occurs when you are doing long running operations on the main thread. The system can't process user interactions during this period since the main thread is blocked. The solution is to do the heavy operations in a worker thread and keep the main thread free.

Answer (score 3):

**The Application Not Responding (ANR) dialog**

As you can imagine, if the main thread is busy with a heavy calculation or reading
data from a network socket, it cannot immediately respond to user input such as a
tap or swipe.

An application that doesn't respond quickly to user interaction will feel
unresponsive—anything more than a couple of hundred milliseconds delay is
noticeable. This is such a pernicious problem that the Android platform protects
users from applications that do too much on the main thread.

**Notice :**

If an app does not respond to user input within fve seconds, the
user will see the Application Not Responding (ANR) dialog and
will be offered the option to quit the application.

The following screenshot shows a typical Android ANR dialog:

[image]

Android works hard to synchronize the user interface redraws with the
hardware-refresh rate. This means that it aims to redraw at the rate of 60 frames per
second—that's just 16.67 ms per frame. If we do work on the main thread that takes
anywhere near 16 ms, we risk affecting the frame rate, resulting in jank—stuttering
animations, jerky scrolling, and so on.

Ideally, of course, we don't want to drop a single frame. Jank, unresponsiveness,
and especially the ANR, offer a very poor user experience, which translates into
bad reviews and unpopular applications. A rule to live by when building Android
applications is: do not block the main thread!

**Notice :**

Android provides a helpful strict mode setting in Developer Options
on each device, which will ﬂash on the screen when applications
perform long-running operations on the main thread.

Further protection was added to the platform in Honeycomb (API level 11) with the
introduction of a new Exception class, NetworkOnMainThreadException, a subclass
of RuntimeException that is thrown if the system detects network activity initiated
on the main thread.

**Source :**

Asynchronous Android Programming - Second Edition - Helder Vasconcelos - July 2016