# IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, illegalstateexception, fragmenttransaction

I'm getting user reports from my app in the market, delivering the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1109)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:399)
at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2066)
at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2044)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2529)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2274)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1803)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1855)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1277)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2269)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1803)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchKeyEvent(TabHost.java:297)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1855)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1277)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2269)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1803)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRoot.java:2880)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2853)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2028)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Apparently it has something to do with a FragmentManager, which I don't use. The stacktrace doesn't show any of my own classes, so I have no idea where this exception occurs and how to prevent it.

For the record: I have a tabhost, and in each tab there is a ActivityGroup switching between Activities.

Comment: I found this question discussing the same issue, but no solution there either.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsav

Comment: While you are not using `FragmentManager`, Honeycomb certainly is. Is this happening on real Honeycomb tablets? Or might it be that somebody is running a hacked Honeycomb on a phone or something and it's that hacked edition that is having difficulty?

Comment: I have no idea. This is the only information I get in the Market Developer Console, the user message contains no useful info either..

Comment: I am using Flurry, which shows me 11 sessions with Android 3.0.1, and I have 11 reports of this exception. Could be coincidence though. Android 3.1 and 3.2 have 56 and 38 sessions, respectively.

Comment: The Market error report has a 'Platform' section, _sometimes_ it has the Android version of the device in it.

Comment: Ah I see, I guess I missed it because it isn't helpful.. _Platforms_
_OTHER_
_11_ _rapporten/week_

Comment: Please check my answer [here][1]. Might be helpful


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa/13987336#13987336

Comment: Here is my solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31016553/3408806
Hope someone resolve this problem.

Comment: The best working answer for me was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62554599/4303296 (not compromising state loss either)

Answer (score 776, accepted):

Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10261438/542091). Basically I just had to :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //No call for super(). Bug on API Level > 11.
}
```

Don't make the call to `super()` on the `saveInstanceState` method. This was messing things up...

This is a known [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19917) in the support package.

If you need to save the instance and add something to your `outState` `Bundle` you can use the following:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY", "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

In the end the proper solution was (as seen in the comments) to use :

```
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

when adding or performing the `FragmentTransaction` that was causing the `Exception`.

Comment: You should use commitAllowingStateLoss() instead of commit()

Comment: This comment about commitAllowingStateLoss() is an answer in its own right - you should post it as that.

Comment: Regarding 'commitAllowingStateLoss' --/> "This is dangerous because the commit can be lost if the activity needs to later be restored from its state, so this should only be used for cases where it is okay for the UI state to change unexpectedly on the user."

Comment: If I look at the v4 source for `popBackStackImmediate` it immediately fails if the state has been saved. Previously adding the fragment with `commitAllowingStateLoss` doesn't play any part. My testing shows this to be true. It has no effect on this specific exception. What we need is a `popBackStackImmediateAllowingStateLoss` method.

Comment: @Ovidiu Looking at sources: Implementation of `Fragment#onSaveInstanceState` is a NOP. Can you explain why not calling `super` method helps ?

Comment: What should i do with dialog fragment? Here we have only call show() method.

Comment: @Synesso, you are actually right. The error gets fired by `popBackStackImmediate()` and not by committing the transaction. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Synesso, maybe there are some conditions we can test for, and avoid calling `popBackStackImmediate()` on those conditions? any idea how to detect these conditions?

Comment: @DanieleB yes, I've posted an answer here. But I've actually found an even better solution by using Otto message bus: register the fragment as a subscriber and listen for the async result from the bus. Unregister on pause and re-register on resume. The async also needs a Produce method for the times when it completes and the fragment is paused. When I get time I'll update my answer with this in more detail.

Comment: @Synesso, catching the exception is actually a good solution! that exception only happens very rarely to me anyway

Comment: Interestingly I only use commitAllowingStateLoss(), tried both workaround in onSaveInstanteState(), still no luck, the issue still occurs once in a while. Only good solution is catching exception, sad.

Comment: Did anyone file an issue that I could star?

Comment: @Ovidiu Latcu Thanks..transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss(); this line saved hours of time..;)

Comment: I think this is not 100% correct, check this link: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: What about dialog fragments? How to commitAllowingStateLoss() while displaying fragment as a dialog.

Comment: I was able to solve it by showing Fragment through a Handler.

Comment: you are probably calling the `fragmentTransaction::commit()` from a background thread (using `runOnUiThread` or `handler` ). The actual commit is happening bit late. If user exits app (calling `onSavedStateInstance()`) fast, then this fts commit actually occurs later; resulting this issue. So the solution at this point probably is to allow state loss `commitAllowingStateLoss()`. User is exiting anyway.

Comment: If you use `commitAllowingStateLoss`, you probably will encounter the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` while the fragmentManager trying to restore its state(not always). Even if I called commit in the `onCreate()` it still threw the `IllegalStateException`. I still can't figure out why. I think it's an Android bug.

Comment: Wow i cant believe its 2017 and the suggestion posted by @meh is still working, android is drop dead buggy

Comment: @IteratioN7T the issue is with doing fragment transactions after callbacks from background jobs when the app is not on the foreground.
best way is to avoid doing it because its a bad practice.

Comment: I use commitAllowingStateLoss for an app on play store and i'm still getting hundreds of the same exception at this line:
fragmentTransaction.replace(layoutId, newFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();

Comment: What is `transaction` here?

Comment: I get this error when I don't call super: _Overriding method should call super.onSaveInstanceState. Some methods, such as View#onDetachedFromWindow, require that you also call the super implementation as part of your method._

Comment: I didn't use onSaveInstanceState() method. Why it crashed sametimes

Answer (score 150):

There are many related problems with a similar error message. Check the second line of this particular stack trace. This exception is specifically related to the call to `FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate`.

This method call, like `popBackStack`, will *always* fail with `IllegalStateException` if the session state has already been saved. Check the source. There is nothing you can do to stop this exception being thrown.

- Removing the call to `super.onSaveInstanceState` will not help.
- Creating the Fragment with `commitAllowingStateLoss` will not help.

Here's how I observed the problem:

- There's a form with a submit button.
- When the button is clicked a dialog is created and an async process starts.
- The user clicks the home key before the process is finished - `onSaveInstanceState` is called.
- The process completes, a callback is made and `popBackStackImmediate` is attempted.
- `IllegalStateException` is thrown.

Here's what I did to solve it:

As it is not possible to avoid the `IllegalStateException` in the callback, catch & ignore it.

```
try {
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(name);
} catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {
    // There's no way to avoid getting this if saveInstanceState has already been called.
}
```

This is enough to stop the app from crashing. But now the user will restore the app and see that the button they thought they'd pressed hasn't been pressed at all (they think). The form fragment is still showing!

To fix this, when the dialog is created, make some state to indicate the process has started.

```
progressDialog.show(fragmentManager, TAG);
submitPressed = true;
```

And save this state in the bundle.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    ...
    outState.putBoolean(SUBMIT_PRESSED, submitPressed);
}
```

Don't forget to load it back again in `onViewCreated`

Then, when resuming, rollback the fragments if submit was previously attempted. This prevents the user from coming back to what seems like an un-submitted form.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (submitPressed) {
        // no need to try-catch this, because we are not in a callback
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(name);
        submitPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting reading about that here: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: If you use DialogFragment, I've made an alternative to it here: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/DialogShard

Comment: What if the `popBackStackImmediate` was called by Android itself?

Comment: Absolutely great. This one should be the accepted answer. Thank you very much! Maybe I would add submitPressed = false; after popBackStackInmediate.

Comment: I didn't use public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)  method. Do I need to set empty method for public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) ?

Comment: @FakhriddinAbdullaev you absolutely need `onSaveInstanceState()`, because the user may rotate the screen while the background task is responding, thus you will get exception again.

Answer (score 63):

Check if the activity `isFinishing()` before showing the fragment and pay attention to `commitAllowingStateLoss()`.

Example:

```
if(!isFinishing()) {
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            DummyFragment dummyFragment = DummyFragment.newInstance();
            ft.add(R.id.dummy_fragment_layout, dummyFragment);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Comment: !isFinishing() && !isDestroyed() doesn't work for me.

Comment: !isFinishing() && !isDestroyed() worked for me, but it requires API 17. But it simply doesn't show a `DialogFragment`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729138/on-showing-dialog-i-get-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate for other good solutions, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41813953/2914140 helped me.

Answer (score 40):

It's October 2017, and Google makes Android Support Library with the new things call Lifecycle component. It provides some new idea for this 'Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState' problem.

**In short:**

- Use lifecycle component to determine if it's correct time for popping up your fragment.

**Longer version with explain:**

- why this problem come out?

  It's because you are trying to use `FragmentManager` from your activity(which is going to hold your fragment I suppose?) to commit a transaction for you fragment. Usually this would look like you are trying to do some transaction for an up coming fragment, meanwhile the host activity already call `savedInstanceState` method(user may happen to touch the home button so the activity calls `onStop()`, in my case it's the reason)

  Usually this problem shouldn't happen -- we always try to load fragment into activity at the very beginning, like the `onCreate()` method is a perfect place for this. But sometimes this **do happen**, especially when you can't decide what fragment you will load to that activity, or you are trying to load fragment from an `AsyncTask` block(or anything will take a little time). The time, before the fragment transaction really happens, but after the activity's `onCreate()` method, user can do anything. If user press the home button, which triggers the activity's `onSavedInstanceState()` method, there would be a `can not perform this action` crash.

  If anyone want to see deeper in this issue, I suggest them to take a look at this blog [post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html). It looks deep inside the source code layer and explain a lot about it. Also, it gives the reason that you shouldn't use the `commitAllowingStateLoss()` method to workaround this crash(trust me it offers nothing good for your code)
- How to fix this?

  - Should I use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` method to load fragment? **Nope you shouldn't**;
  - Should I override `onSaveInstanceState` method, ignore `super` method inside it? **Nope you shouldn't**;
  - Should I use the magical `isFinishing` inside activity, to check if the host activity is at the right moment for fragment transaction? Yeah this **looks like** the right way to do.
- Take a look at what [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html) component can do.

  Basically, Google makes some implementation inside the `AppCompatActivity` class(and several other base class you should use in your project), which makes it a easier to **determine current lifecycle state**. Take a look back to our problem: why would this problem happen? It's because we do something at the wrong timing. So we try not to do it, and this problem will be gone.

  I code a little for my own project, here is what I do using `LifeCycle`. I code in Kotlin.

```
val hostActivity: AppCompatActivity? = null // the activity to host fragments. It's value should be properly initialized.

fun dispatchFragment(frag: Fragment) {
    hostActivity?.let {
       if(it.lifecyclecurrentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)){
           showFragment(frag)
       }
    }
}

private fun showFragment(frag: Fragment) {
    hostActivity?.let {
        Transaction.begin(it, R.id.frag_container)
                .show(frag)
                .commit()
    }
```

As I show above. I will check the lifecycle state of the host activity. With Lifecycle component within support library, this could be more specific. The code `lifecyclecurrentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)` means, if current state is at least `onResume`, not later than it? Which makes sure my method won't be execute during some other life state(like `onStop`).

- Is it all done?

  Of course not. The code I have shown tells some new way to prevent application from crashing. But if it do go to the state of `onStop`, that line of code wont do things and thus show nothing on your screen. When users come back to the application, they will see an empty screen, that's the empty host activity showing no fragments at all. It's bad experience(yeah a little bit better than a crash).

  So here I wish there could be something nicer: app won't crash if it comes to life state later than `onResume`, the transaction method is life state aware; besides, the activity will try continue to finished that fragment transaction action, after the user come back to our app.

  I add something more to this method:

```
class FragmentDispatcher(_host: FragmentActivity) : LifecycleObserver {
    private val hostActivity: FragmentActivity? = _host
    private val lifeCycle: Lifecycle? = _host.lifecycle
    private val profilePendingList = mutableListOf<BaseFragment>()

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    fun resume() {
        if (profilePendingList.isNotEmpty()) {
            showFragment(profilePendingList.last())
        }
    }

    fun dispatcherFragment(frag: BaseFragment) {
        if (lifeCycle?.currentState?.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) == true) {
            showFragment(frag)
        } else {
            profilePendingList.clear()
            profilePendingList.add(frag)
        }
    }

    private fun showFragment(frag: BaseFragment) {
        hostActivity?.let {
            Transaction.begin(it, R.id.frag_container)
                    .show(frag)
                    .commit()
        }
    }
}
```

I maintain a list inside this `dispatcher` class, to store those fragment don't have chance to finish the transaction action. And when user come back from home screen and found there is still fragment waiting to be launched, it will go to the `resume()` method under the `@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)` annotation. Now I think it should be working like I expected.

Comment: It would be nice to use Java instead of Kotlin

Comment: Why does your implementation of the `FragmentDispatcher` use a list to store pending fragments if there will be only one fragment restored?

Comment: I prefer this answer. Thanks!

If working with FragmentTransactions, we should wait at least to be in the START state, to prevent crashes.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html#lco
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#suspend

Answer (score 22):

Here is a different solution to this problem.

Using a private member variable you are able to set the returned data as an intent that can then be processed after super.onResume();

Like so:

```
private Intent mOnActivityResultIntent = null; 

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mOnActivityResultIntent != null){
        ... do things ...
        mOnActivityResultIntent = null;
    }
 }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(data != null){
        mOnActivityResultIntent = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on what action you were doing that wasn't allowed, this might need to move to an even later moment than onResume(). For insatcne, if FragmentTransaction.commit() is the problem, this needs to go into onPostResume() instead.

Comment: This is THE answer to this question for me. Since I needed to forward a received NFC tag to the previous activity, this is what did it for me.

Comment: For me it was happening because I was not calling `super.onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 22):

**Short And working Solution :**

Follow Simple Steps

Steps

Step 1 : Override `onSaveInstanceState` state in respective fragment. And remove super method from it.

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {

}
```

Step 2 : Use 
`fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss( );`

instead of  `fragmentTransaction.commit( );`  while fragment operations.

Comment: Answer  is not copied or refereed form else where .Is was posted to help to people by  my working solution which is got by several trial and error

Answer (score 14):

**BEWARE**, using `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()` could result in a bad experience for the user. For more information on why this exception is thrown, see [this post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html).

Comment: This does not provide answer to the question, you must provide a valid answer for the question

Answer (score 10):

I found a dirty solution for this kind of problem. If you still want to keep your `ActivityGroups` for whatever reason (I had time limitation reasons), you just implement

```
public void onBackPressed() {}
```

in your `Activity` and do some `back` code in there. even if there is no such Method on older Devices, this Method gets called by newer ones.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use commitAllowingStateLoss(), it should only be used for cases where it is okay for the UI state to change unexpectedly on the user.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitAllowingStateLoss()

If the transaction happens in ChildFragmentManager of parentFragment, use 
**parentFragment.isResume()** outside to check instead.

```
if (parentFragment.isResume()) {
    DummyFragment dummyFragment = DummyFragment.newInstance();
    transaction = childFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    trans.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, startFragment);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, the scenario was like this:

- My Activity is adding/replacing list fragments.
- Each list fragment has a reference to the activity, to notify the activity when a list item is clicked (observer pattern).
- Each list fragment calls **setRetainInstance(true);** in its **onCreate** method.

The **onCreate** method of the **activity** was like this:

```
mMainFragment = (SelectionFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (mMainFragment == null) {
            mMainFragment = new SelectionFragment();

            mMainFragment.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.item_main_menu, getResources().getStringArray(
                            R.array.main_menu)));
mMainFragment.setOnSelectionChangedListener(this);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.content, mMainFragment, MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
            transaction.commit();
        }
```

The exception was thrown because the when configuration changes (device rotated), the activity is created, the main fragment is retrieved from the history of the fragment manager and at the same time the fragment already has an **OLD** reference to the **destroyed activity**

changing the implementation to this solved the problem:

```
mMainFragment = (SelectionFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (mMainFragment == null) {
            mMainFragment = new SelectionFragment();

            mMainFragment.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.item_main_menu, getResources().getStringArray(
                            R.array.main_menu)));
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.content, mMainFragment, MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        mMainFragment.setOnSelectionChangedListener(this);
```

**you need to set your listeners each time the activity is created to avoid the situation where the fragments have references to old destroyed instances of the activity.**

Answer (score 5):

If you inherit from `FragmentActivity`, you must call the superclass in `onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    ...
}
```

If you don't do this and try to show a fragment dialog box in that method, you may get OP's `IllegalStateException`. (To be honest, I don't quite understand *why* the super call fixes the problem. `onActivityResult()` is called before `onResume()`, so it should still not be allowed to show a fragment dialog box.)

Comment: Would love to know why this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 5):

**Fragment transactions should not be executed after `Activity.onStop()` !**
Check that you do not have any callbacks that could execute transaction after `onStop()`. It is better to fix the reason instead of trying to walk around the problem with approaches like `.commitAllowingStateLoss()`

Answer (score 4):

Possibly the smoothest and the simplest solution I found in my case was to avoid popping the offending fragment off the stack in response to activity result. So changing this call in my `onActivityResult()`:

```
popMyFragmentAndMoveOn();
```

to this:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        popMyFragmentAndMoveOn();
    }
}
```

helped in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this exception when i was pressing back button to cancel intent chooser on my map fragment activity.
I resolved this by replacing the code of onResume(where i was initializing the fragment) to onstart() and the app is working fine.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Courtesy: [Solution for IllegalStateException](https://androidclarified.wordpress.com/2018/06/13/illegalstateexception-cannot-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate/)

This issue had annoyed me for a lot of time but fortunately I came with a concrete solution for it. A detailed explanation of it is [here](https://androidclarified.wordpress.com/2018/06/13/illegalstateexception-cannot-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate/).

Using commitAllowStateloss() might prevent this exception but would lead to UI irregularities.So far we have understood that IllegalStateException is encountered when we try to commit a fragment after the Activity state is lost- so we should just delay the transaction until the state is restored.It can be simply done like this

Declare two private boolean variables

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Boolean variable to mark if the transaction is safe
    private boolean isTransactionSafe;

    //Boolean variable to mark if there is any transaction pending
    private boolean isTransactionPending;
```

Now in onPostResume() and onPause we set and unset our boolean variable isTransactionSafe. Idea is to mark trasnsaction safe only when the activity is in foreground so there is no chance of stateloss.

```
/*
onPostResume is called only when the activity's state is completely restored. In this we will
set our boolean variable to true. Indicating that transaction is safe now
 */
public void onPostResume(){
    super.onPostResume();
    isTransactionSafe=true;
}
/*
onPause is called just before the activity moves to background and also before onSaveInstanceState. In this
we will mark the transaction as unsafe
 */

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    isTransactionSafe=false;

}

private void commitFragment(){
    if(isTransactionSafe) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

-What we have done so far will save from IllegalStateException but our transactions will be lost if they are done after the activity moves to background, kind of like commitAllowStateloss(). To help with that we have isTransactionPending boolean variable

```
public void onPostResume(){
   super.onPostResume();
   isTransactionSafe=true;
/* Here after the activity is restored we check if there is any transaction pending from
the last restoration
*/
   if (isTransactionPending) {
      commitFragment();
   }
}


private void commitFragment(){

 if(isTransactionSafe) {
     MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, myFragment);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
     isTransactionPending=false;
 }else {
     /*
     If any transaction is not done because the activity is in background. We set the
     isTransactionPending variable to true so that we can pick this up when we come back to
foreground
     */
     isTransactionPending=true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

as you can see in your crash report, the last line that is throwing the exception is

```
checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1109)
```

if you look at the implementation of checkStateLoss

```
private void checkStateLoss() {
    if (isStateSaved()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState");
    }
}
```

so a simple solution for me is to find what ever method of the Fragment Manager you are calling in your app that eventually leads to this method being called and simply check if isStateSaved() is false before calling that method. For me it was the show() method. I did like this

```
if (!isStateSaved()) {
  myDialog.show(fragmentManager, Tag)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();` is not best solution.
This exception will be thrown when activity's configuration changed and fragment `onSavedInstanceState()` is called and thereafter your async callback method tries to commit fragment.

Simple solution could be check whether activity is changing configuration or not

e.g. check `isChangingConfigurations()`

i.e.

`if(!isChangingConfigurations()) {
    //commit transaction.
}`

Checkout [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) link as well

Comment: Somehow I got this exception when the user clicks on something (the click is the trigger to do the transaction-commit ). How could this be? Would your solution here here?

Comment: @androiddeveloper what else are you doing on user click. somehow fragment is saving its state before you commit the transaction

Comment: The exception was thrown on the exact line of transaction commit. Also, I had a weird typo: instead of "here here" I meant "work here" .

Comment: @androiddeveloper you are right! but before committing transaction are you spawning any background thread or something?

Comment: I don't think so (sorry I'm out of the office), but why would it matter? It's all UI stuff here... If I ever make something on a background thread, I would have exceptions there, plus I don't put UI related stuff on background threads, as it's too risky.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is threw here (In FragmentActivity):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mFragments.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In `FragmentManager.popBackStatckImmediate()`，`FragmentManager.checkStateLoss()` is called firstly. That's the cause of `IllegalStateException`. See the implementation below:

```
private void checkStateLoss() {
    if (mStateSaved) { // Boom!
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState");
    }
    if (mNoTransactionsBecause != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Can not perform this action inside of " + mNoTransactionsBecause);
    }
}
```

I solve this problem simply by using a flag to mark Activity's current status. Here's my solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * A flag that marks whether current Activity has saved its instance state
     */
    private boolean mHasSaveInstanceState;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        mHasSaveInstanceState = true;
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mHasSaveInstanceState = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!mHasSaveInstanceState) {
            // avoid FragmentManager.checkStateLoss()'s throwing IllegalStateException
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are trying to load a fragment in your activity make sure that activity is in resume and not going to pause state.In pause state you may end up losing commit operation that is done.

You can use transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss() instead of transaction.commit() to load fragment

or

Create a boolean and check if activity is not going to onpause

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mIsResumed = true;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mIsResumed = false;
    super.onPause();
}
```

then while loading fragment check

```
if(mIsResumed){
//load the your fragment
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing some FragmentTransaction in onActivityResult what you can do you can set some boolean value inside onActivityResult then in onResume you can do your FragmentTransaction on the basis of the boolean value. Please refer the code below.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume;
    if(isSwitchFragment){
        isSwitchFragment=false;
        bottomNavigationView.getTabAt(POS_FEED).select();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == FilterActivity.FILTER_REQUEST_EVENT && data != null) {
        isSwitchFragment=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code as an image, use code formatting instead.

Comment: Yes it helped me.., This the exact and proper solution for marshmallow device i got this exception and solved with this simple trick..!! Hence up voted.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to @Anthonyeef great answer, here is a sample code in Java:

```
private boolean shouldShowFragmentInOnResume;

private void someMethodThatShowsTheFragment() {

    if (this.getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)) {
        showFragment();
    } else {
        shouldShowFragmentInOnResume = true;
    }
}

private void showFragment() {
    //Your code here
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (shouldShowFragmentInOnResume) {
        shouldShowFragmentInOnResume = false;
        showFragment();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have crash with popBackStack() or popBackStackImmediate() method please try fixt with:

```
        if (!fragmentManager.isStateSaved()) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
        }
```

This is worked for me as well.

Comment: Note that it requires API 26 and above

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got this error in an override method called onActivityResult. After digging I just figure out maybe I needed to call '**super**' before.
I added it and it just worked

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); //<--- THIS IS THE SUPPER CALL
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
        mostrarFragment(FiltroFragment.newInstance())
    }

}
```

Maybe you just need to add a 'super' on any override you are doing before your code.

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin extension**

```
fun FragmentManager?.replaceAndAddToBackStack(
    @IdRes containerViewId: Int,
    fragment: () -> Fragment,
    tag: String
) {
    // Find and synchronously remove a fragment with the same tag.
    // The second transaction must start after the first has finished.
    this?.findFragmentByTag(tag)?.let {
        beginTransaction().remove(it).commitNow()
    }
    // Add a fragment.
    this?.beginTransaction()?.run {
        replace(containerViewId, fragment, tag)
        // The next line will add the fragment to a back stack.
        // Remove if not needed.
        // You can use null instead of tag, but tag is needed for popBackStack(), 
        // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59158254/2914140
        addToBackStack(tag)
    }?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

Usage:

```
val fragment = { SomeFragment.newInstance(data) }
fragmentManager?.replaceAndAddToBackStack(R.id.container, fragment, SomeFragment.TAG)
```

Comment: You can remove the () -> before Fragment

Comment: @Claire, thanks! Do you mean changing to `fragment: Fragment`? Yes, I tried this variant, but in this case a fragment would be created in all cases (even when fragmentManager == null, but I didn't encounter this situation). I updated the answer and changed null to tag in `addToBackStack()`.

Answer (score 2):

change `getFragmentManager()`  to `getChildFragmentManager()`. Don't use parent `FragmentManager`, try to use self.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from support library version 24.0.0 you can call `FragmentTransaction.commitNow()` method which commits this transaction synchronously instead of calling `commit()` followed by `executePendingTransactions()`. As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitNow()) says this approach even better:

> Calling commitNow is preferable to calling commit() followed by executePendingTransactions() as the latter will have the side effect of attempting to commit all currently pending transactions whether that is the desired behavior or not.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is an accepted answer by @Ovidiu Latcu but after some while, error still persist.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     //No call for super(). Bug on API Level > 11.
}
```

Crashlytics still sending me this weird error message.

However error now occurring only on version 7+ (Nougat)
My fix was to use **commitAllowingStateLoss()** instead of commit() at the fragmentTransaction.

This [post](https://medium.com/inloopx/demystifying-androids-commitallowingstateloss-cb9011a544cc) is helpful for commitAllowingStateLoss() and never had a fragment issue ever again.

To sum it up, the accepted answer here might work on pre Nougat android versions.

This might save someone a few hours of searching. 
happy codings. <3 cheers

Answer (score 1):

To bypass this issue, we can use [The Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) , which was introduced in Google I/O 2018.
The Navigation Architecture Component simplifies the implementation of navigation in an Android app.

Comment: It's not good enough, and bugy (poor deeplink handling, can't save state show/hide fragments and some important issue that is still open)

Answer (score 1):

This error `IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` occurs when you trying to create or replace a fragment while the parent activity or parent fragment is in a **Stop State** and **UI doesn't exist**.

**Q. How can this state occur?**.

**A.** When your parent activity or parent fragment is already in a stop state. This can happen when your app is trying to move to a new fragment while the user puts your app back to the background.

**Q. Apparently it has something to do with a FragmentManager, which I don't use. The stacktrace doesn't show any of my own classes, so I have no idea where this exception occurs and how to prevent it**

**A.** When you attach a `ViewPager` with `Fragments`. It internally uses `FragmentManager` to place fragments.

**Q. How to handle it?**

**A.** There are some solutions that others already give but I think you **should not** use a workaround to avoid this problem. It is a genuine  problem and you should handle it gracefully.

You can use the below code to know whether the activity is in a **stop state** before placing fragments or attaching a viewpager

```
if(supportFragmentManager.isStateSaved.not()){
        // safe to attach viewpager or fragments
  }
```

Use `childFragmentManager.isStateSaved` if inside the parent fragment before placing fragments or attaching viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your activity

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (outState.isEmpty()) {
        // Work-around for a pre-Android 4.2 bug
        outState.putBoolean("bug:fix", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this issue and problem occurs every time when context of your `FragmentActivity` gets changed (e.g. Screen orientation is changed, etc.). So the best fix for it is to update context from your `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with creating a base fragment and make all fragments in my app extend it

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    private boolean mStateSaved;

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        mStateSaved = true;
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    /**
     * Version of {@link #show(FragmentManager, String)} that no-ops when an IllegalStateException
     * would otherwise occur.
     */
    public void showAllowingStateLoss(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        // API 26 added this convenient method
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (manager.isStateSaved()) {
                return;
            }
        }

        if (mStateSaved) {
            return;
        }

        show(manager, tag);
    }
}
```

Then when I try to show a fragment I use `showAllowingStateLoss` instead of `show`

like this:

```
MyFragment.newInstance()
.showAllowingStateLoss(getFragmentManager(), MY_FRAGMENT.TAG);
```

I came up to this solution from this PR: https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions/pull/170/files

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround, which I'm not sure if helps in all cases (origin [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37094575#comment28)) :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        final View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        if (rootView != null) {
            rootView.cancelPendingInputEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.
It happened because of the destruction of previous activity.
when ı backed the previous activity it was destroyed.
I put it base activity (WRONG)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SpinnerCustom2.setFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    onCreateDrawerActivity(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I put it into onStart it was RIGHT

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SpinnerCustom2.setFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gian Gomen In my case call SUPER solves problem. It seems like more correct solution then commitAllowingStateLoss(), because it solves problem, not hide it.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
     final int requestCode,
     @NonNull final String[] permissions, 
     @NonNull final int[] grantResults
) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions, grantResults); //<--- Without this line crash 
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    onPermissionGranted(Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_STORAGE);
                }
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use remove() instead of popup() if state saved.

```
   private void removeFragment() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager.isStateSaved()) {
        List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
        if (fragments != null && !fragments.isEmpty()) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in my case, there were errors in my xml files. I added spaces between buttons and text boxes that were no longer allowed. When I removed them, I did not receive any report of this error.[image]