# On Rotation I get "Unable to destroy activity ... Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"

Tags: android, rotation, android-fragments, acl, onconfigurationchanged

Hi and thank you for any help.

I am only at the very beginning of configuring my code to handle rotation: I have implemented onDestroy(), but not yet any onSaveInstanceState() or onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() because I am figuring out what will not cause problems if destroyed and recreated after rotation and what needs to be saved.

In my application I use a Service that runs an AsyncTask, and 3 fragments that get swapped on user pressing buttons.

I use the compatibility library for managing the fragments.

I suspect the error I encounter is related to the fragments;

**To be specific, I would prefer the fragments to be destroyed and recreated on rotation, rather that preserving  them 
(because it is my hope that this would make my code simpler...)**

when I rotate the emulator I get the error in the title.

This is the code of the main activity:

```
public class Quotes extends FragmentActivity {

    private String url2;
    //public String responseBody;
    public static ArrayList<Stock> lt;
    public static ArrayList<Stock> best;
    public static ArrayList<Stock> worst;
    public static ArrayList<Stock> fav;// =new ArrayList<Stock>();
    public static LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound;// = false;
    public MyAdapter myAdap;
    public Messenger messenger;
    public Messenger messenger2;
    public Grab g;
    public static Handler handler;
    public static  Handler handler2;
    public Intent intent;
    public ListView lv;
    public dettagliofragment fragment;
    public listafragment fragmentlista ;
    public static boolean tablet;//=true;
    public static WorstBest worstbest;
    public static favouritesFragment fragmentfavourites;
    public static FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
    public static int stack;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> stackArray; // stackArray =new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
        stackArray =new ArrayList<Integer>();
        fav =new ArrayList<Stock>();
        tablet=true;
        mBound = false;
        fragmentActivity = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        url2=getString(R.string.url2);
        g = new Grab(url2);
        String s = g.vai();
        //Log.e("", s);
        Log.e("", "passo oltre l'invocazione al grab");
        lt = new MyParser(s).parseResp();
        fragmentlista = new listafragment();
        fragmentfavourites= new favouritesFragment() ;
        worstbest = new WorstBest();
        /////////////////primo message handler
        handler=new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Message mess=msg;   
            Log.e("","MESSAGGIO RICEVUTO");
            lt = mService.ritira();
            Log.e("what?", Integer.toString(mess.what));
            if( mess.what==0){

                worst=mService.ritiraWorst();
                best=mService.ritiraBest();
                fav=mService.ritiraFav();
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                 View view1=(View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
                View view2=(View)findViewById(R.id.view2);
                if(view2==null) {tablet=false;};
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();       
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view1, fragmentlista);
                if(tablet){fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view2, worstbest);}
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                g.fermaGrab(); 
                Log.e("", "fermograb");
                    };

            }
        };
        messenger = new Messenger(handler); 

        intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
         intent.putExtra("messenger", messenger);       

        /////////////////secondo message handler
        handler2=new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            Message mess=msg;   
            Log.e("","SECONDO MESSAGGIO RICEVUTO");
            lt = mService.ritira();
            worst=mService.ritiraWorst();
            best=mService.ritiraBest();
            fav=mService.ritiraFav();
            if(lt==null){Log.e("","lt è nullo");};
            if(fragmentlista==null){Log.e("","fragmentlista è nullo");};

            fragmentlista.prendiLista(lt);
            worstbest.prendiListaWorst(worst);
            worstbest.prendiListaBest(best);
            if(fav.size()>0)fragmentfavourites.prendiLista(fav);
            };
            };
        messenger2 = new Messenger(handler2);  
        intent.putExtra("messenger2", messenger2);

        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } 

    public static void layoutSchermo(int conf){

    if(conf==1){    
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        if(!tablet){fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.view1, fragmentfavourites);}
        if(tablet){fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.view2, fragmentfavourites);}
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        stack=fragmentTransaction.commit();
        stackArray.add(stack);
        Log.e("","stack = "+ Integer.toString(stack));
        }
    if(conf==2){    
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        if(!tablet){fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.view1, worstbest);}
        if(tablet){fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.view2, worstbest);}
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);   
        stack= fragmentTransaction.commit();
        stackArray.add(stack);
        Log.e("","stack = "+ Integer.toString(stack));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(stackArray.size()>0)
            {for(int i=1;i<stackArray.size();i++){
                fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(stackArray.get(i),     FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);}
            }

        super.onBackPressed(); 
    }   


     protected void onStop() {
            Log.e("onstop","passo per onstop");   

            mService.stop();
            g.fermaGrab();
            super.onStop();    
            }
     protected void onPause() {
            Log.e("onpause","passo per onpause");   
            mService.stop();
            g.fermaGrab();
            super.onPause();       
        }


     protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("ondestroy","passo per ondestroy"); 
        mService.stop();
        g.fermaGrab();
        //handler.removeMessages(333); 
        stopService(intent);
        //g=null;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(stackArray.size()>0)
            {for(int i=1;i<stackArray.size();i++){
                fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(stackArray.get(i),     FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);}
            }

         super.onDestroy();   

        }

     @Override
     protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {  }  


    public static ArrayList<Stock> dammi(){
        return lt;
    }  

    public void inizia()
    {   
        Log.e("","il serlizio è bound ? "+ mBound);
        mService.prendi(lt);
        mService.getNumber();


    }           

       private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            //@Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                    IBinder service) {
                Log.e("", "sono in ServiceConnection");
                // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
                LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
                mService = binder.getService();
                mBound = true;
                //inizia();
                mService.prendi(lt);
                mService.getNumber();

            }

            //@Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                mBound = false;
                mService = null;
            }
        };
```

Hes is my LogCat:

```
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.quotes/com.example.quotes.Quotes}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3273)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3291)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3489)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1314)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:480)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at com.example.quotes.Quotes.onDestroy(Quotes.java:201)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5172)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1109)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
01-06 12:20:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2165):     ... 12 more
```

Thank you very much for any help !!!

Comment: Can you shift your troubling code to onConfigurationChanged()

Comment: I mean to say if it is not alllowing you to  pop back fragments in OnDestroy then write that code in onConfigurationChanged Method, this will be called on orientation change

Comment: @ChangdeoJadhav no success. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your info. Meanwhile, I fixed this issue.

What was causing the problem was a Service that needed to be unbound when the Activty was destroyed because of rotation.

As far as I could understand the Fragments are not destroyed when the activity is destroyed. However, I would appreciate any comment on this.

So, I reinitialized the Fragments on the `onCreate()` method when the Activty is created again after destruction, and this is not causing trouble to the application.

```
protected void onDestroy() {
   mService.stop();
   stopService(new Intent(this, LocalService.class));
   unbindService(mConnection);
   g.fermaGrab();
   stopService(intent);
   Log.e("ondestroy","passostopService(intent)"); 
   super.onDestroy();       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because the other answers to this question led me on a wild goose hunt of WeakReferences, memory leaks, and onResumeFragments... you can get this error simply by having an `onFocusChangeListener` that tries to pop up a dialog box when a control loses focus. The error comes in `ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity` so it's a little tough to figure out.

Comment: This just helped me solve a bug when launching my app on an Android 7.1 tablet, I don't know why it was made like this but I added a version check and it just works now:

`if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)` then setOnFocusChangeListener

Comment: Actually I'm testing and it also happens in 8 and 8.1, in Android 9 (Build.VERSION_CODES.P) it is fixed

Comment: Nice job StackOverflow, keeping this answer around for ten years just so it could help its first person! I wonder if there's an achievement for that. Glad it worked for you.