# Can't create DialogFragment in onPostResume() - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I've got a DialogFragment that I try to create in the overridden onPostResume() method of my Activity, but I get this error message:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

I've read all the answers to similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177781/java-lang-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstanc?rq=1), [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=23096), and the blog [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)), but none of them worked for me (the onPostResume fix or the Runnable fix), or aren't suitable - I don't want to use commitAllowingStateLoss because it's unsafe, and I don't want to override onSaveInstanceState without calling super().

Edit: I've narrowed down the issue to my use of Eventbus.  When I create the dialog fragment directly in the onPostResume method, I don't get any errors.  When I call the eventbus event to create the dialog fragment, I get the aforementioned error.  I have tried changing the event handler's thread to both:

```
public void onEvent(DisplayOperatorDialogEvent event)
public void onEventMainThread(DisplayOperatorDialogEvent event)
```

but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

The code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostResume()
{
    super.onPostResume();
    Log.d("MainActivity","in onPostResume");
    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
    String receivedAction = receivedIntent.getAction();//null if started from the menu
    try
    {
        String receivedText;
        if(receivedAction!=null && receivedAction.equals("display_dialog"))
        {
            receivedText = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("dialog");
            if(receivedText!=null && receivedText.equals("operator"))
            {
                String title = "hello";
                String msg = "test";
                DisplayOperatorDialogEvent dialogEvent = new DisplayOperatorDialogEvent(title, msg);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(dialogEvent);
            }
        }
        receivedIntent.setAction("");
        receivedIntent.removeExtra("screen");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Error: parse the notification screen intent: ", "" + e);
    } 
}

public void onEvent(DisplayOperatorDialogEvent event)
{
    {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("operator");
        if (prev != null)
        {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        operatorDialog = new OperatorDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", event.getTitle());
        args.putString("message", event.getMsg());
        operatorDialog.show(ft,"operator");
    }
}
```

The traceback:

```
10-05 19:06:43.115  20803-20803/com.unifiapp E/Event﹕ Could not dispatch event: class com.unifiapp.events.Events$DisplayOperatorDialogEvent to subscribing class class com.unifiapp.MainActivity
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1360)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1378)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:155)
        at com.unifiapp.MainActivity.onEvent(MainActivity.java:478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:569)
        at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:500)
        at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:475)
        at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:365)
        at com.unifiapp.MainActivity.onPostResume(MainActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5323)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2764)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This issue happens on both Android 4.0 and 4.4.

Comment: Did you find something about?