# Remove fragment from activity on onResume android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am adding fragment on **onCreate** using this code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Sometimes I have to remove it on **onResume** using this code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(splashFragment).commit();
```

getting **exception**:
“IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState”

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting exception "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Handler` to commit the transaction as it is creating Activity state loss in the `onResume` method. Information came from [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177781/java-lang-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstanc) and http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

If you are using `FragmentActivity` do fragment transaction in `onResumeFragments()` or in `Activity` `onPostResume()`