# How to get crash point for below error . it doesn't show me the line no

Tags: java, android

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1500)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1518)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:634)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:613)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:282)
   at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12779)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2592)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2599)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2599)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2599)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2599)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2599)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2599)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2599)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1063)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5993)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: write your functionality inside the try{}catch(Exception e){} then you debug

Comment: Thanks muruga5000 i'll try it

Comment: please if  not able to give answer then please don't mark as negative

Comment: post what you tried@Mehulsinh

Comment: @muruga5000 try catch is not feasible solution I have lots of code i didn't understand where to put it.

Comment: which page or Activity you got error@Mehulsinh

Comment: if you debug line by line you still cant find the position ?

Comment: I have solved it by removing my  super.onSaveInstanceState(saveInstance)

Answer (score 1):

Error is:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

This error is more related to method calling order. I meant, you probably called some method but activity/fragment is in a state where it can not process that method.

This can be caused also by a fragment transaction at wrong time.

That's why you don't find the line number in the log.

You can search for this error and you will see different root causes. This may at least guide you to find the problematic point.

Please, update your question with "onSaveInstanceState" method. This way, we can try to help you more.

Or share more code....

For now, use these answers as reference:

[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit)

[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177781/java-lang-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstanc)

[Question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa)

Comment: @Guliherme P Thanks for your reply , i have found my answer in your Question1 link.

Comment: Terrific! I'm glad that I help you!