# IllegalStateException on AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, illegalstateexception

I'm getting a following error when trying to replace a fragment upon receiving a response from AsyncTask:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

The thing is, I get this error randomly upon restarting my app through Android Studio. In a simplified version my activity contains 4 key methods (onCreate, taskCompleted, parseJSON and fragmentReplace), that determine which fragment should the user see at the start:

```
private AsyncTask mMyTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMyTask = new AsyncTask(this, this);
    mMyTask.executeTaskCall("check_user");
}


@Override
public void taskCompleted(String results) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(results);
        parseJSON(jsonBody);
    }
    catch (JSONException je){
    }
}

private void parseJSON(JSONObject jsonBody) throws JSONException {
    boolean userActive = jsonBody.getBoolean("result");

    if (userActive){
        fragmentReplace(new FirstFragment(), "FirstFragment");
    }
    else {
        fragmentReplace(new SecondFragment(), "SecondFragment");
    }
}

public void fragmentReplace(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag){
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.layout_container, fragment, fragmentTag)
            .commit();
}
```

What is the reason of this exception happening so random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read WeakReference solution (or may be other also) at [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177781/java-lang-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstanc).

---

There is one alternate solution for this problem. Using flag you can handle it, like below

```
/**
 * Flag to avoid "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
 * onSaveInstanceState". Avoid Fragment transaction until onRestoreInstanceState or onResume
 * gets called.
 */
private boolean isOnSaveInstanceStateCalled = false;


@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(final Bundle bundle) {
    .....
    isOnSaveInstanceStateCalled = false;
    .....
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
    .....
    isOnSaveInstanceStateCalled = true;
    .....
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isOnSaveInstanceStateCalled = false;
    .....
}
```

And you can check this `boolean` value while doing fragment transaction.

```
private void fragmentReplace(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag){
    if (!isOnSaveInstanceStateCalled) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.layout_container, fragment, fragmentTag)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

---

Update for API 26.1+ (contributed by [Stephen M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1876980/stephen-m))

[Fragment.isStateSaved()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#isStateSaved()) has been added since 26.1.0, which can also be used for same purpose.

Comment: Starting in API 26 you might be able to call fragment.isStateSaved() instead of keeping the state yourself.

Comment: @StephenM That's great. Let me look into this method and update the answer. Thank you for valuable information

Comment: I think the current answer is useful for people who are running before API 26.

Comment: @StephenM Yes correct. Please see updated answer.