# Navigating to DialogFragment produces IllegalArgumentException if button pressed quickly?

Tags: android, android-navigation

My `Navigation` graph has two destinations, a `Fragment` and a `DialogFragment`. The `Fragment` contains a `Button` that navigates to the `DialogFragment` when pressed.

Everything works as expected, *except* if I click the button very quickly. Doing so can trigger a

> IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination
>   com.example.app:id/show_dialog is unknown to this NavController

To fix this, I ensure that the current destination is the `Fragment` containing the `show_dialog` action:

```
val navController = findNavController()
val currentDest = navController.currentDestination?.id

if (currentDest == R.id.test_fragment) {
    navController.navigate(TestFragmentDirections.showDialog())
}
```

Making this change appears to fix the issue. However, I would like to know:

> **Why** is it necessary to wrap the `navigate` call with a conditional statement in this situation?

Comment: you could avoid all this talk with just a `try/catch/finally` block

Comment: Yeah, but I'm interested to know *why* I have to do this check at that particular time. I plan on doing a lot of work with Jetpack components in the future, so it's good to know.

Comment: I see what you mean now, I can use a `try/catch` to help me get to the bottom of things. Will do. Thanks.

Comment: i will use an answer for that

Comment: Check this [issue ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118975714) to see Android's answer for the problem

Comment: Thanks, Sanlok. I guess what's happening is I'm clicking the Show Dialog button fast enough that it registers two clicks. The fragment is notified of the first click and navigates to the dialog. It is still notified of the second click because it is STARTED while the dialog is on screen?

Comment: According to that issue ticket, it's fixed in `Fragment 1.1.0alpha01`, but I'm seeing my test project has a transient dependency on `Fragment 1.1.0alpha09`

Comment: Yes I can also confirm that this is not really 100% fixed. I think your theory about multiple click being registered is true. I have also found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060762/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-navigation-destination-xxx-is-unknown-to-thi?noredirect=1&lq=1) discussing about the solution. Addition to these, if you have only one button in each screen, I think you can also try implementing debounced click listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is just based on the Android inside Architecture and is also dependent on the hardware performance. Just wrap it in a `try/catch` block:

```
try{
  findNavController().navigate(TestFragmentDirections.showDialog())
}catch(e: IllegalArgumentException){
    e.printStackTrace
}
```

Comment: You're right, I'll have to just accept it until I become more familiar with the inner workings. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting [IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382929/illegalstateexception-when-trying-to-show-dialog-fragment) because if you see showDialog() method, you will find implementation as below:

```
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    mDismissed = false;
    mShownByMe = true;
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commit();
}
```

I'll suggest to write your own `showDialog` menthod with below implementation:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .add(dialog, "TAG")
               .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```