# findFragmentByTag() returns null after perform a FragmentTransaction using replace() method

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

My Android app consists three **fragments: A, B and C**. They're loaded in the two containers defined in the `MainActivity` layout.

When the app is started, it shows the **fragmentA loaded in the left_container** and the **fragmentC in the right_container**.

If you press the button in the **fragmentA**, a `FragmentTransaction` changes **FragmentC** by **FragmentB**.

At the moment everything OK. **But the trouble appears when I try to get a reference to the loaded fragmentB using** `findFragmentByTag()`, because it returns `null`. I've used the method replace in the `FragmentTransaction` and I've finished it with `commit()`, but there isn't way to call **FragmentB** method. My code:

MainActivity.java:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity{
 static String fragmentTag = "FRAGMENTB_TAG";

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Adds the left container's fragment
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.left_container, new FragmentA()).commit(); //Adds the fragment A to the left container

    //Adds the right container's fragment
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.right_container, new FragmentC()).commit(); //Adds the Fragment C to the right container
 }

 /**
 * Called when the button "Activate Fragment B" is pressed
 */
public void buttonListener(View v){

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.right_container, new FragmentB(),fragmentTag); //Replaces the Fragment C previously in the right_container with a new Fragment B
        ft.commit(); //Finishes the transaction


        //!!HERE THE APP CRASHES (java.lang.NullPointerException = findFragmentByTag returns null
        ((FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag)).testView();


    }
}
```

FragmentB.java:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container,false);

}


/**
 * Gets a reference to the text_fragment_b TextView and calls its method setText(), changing "It doesn't work" text by "It works!"
 */
public void testView(){
    TextView tv = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.text_fragment_b);
    tv.setText("It works!");
}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/left_container" android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>    
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/right_container" android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_weight="50" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_b.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_margin="5sp">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text_fragment_b"
    android:text="It doesn't works!"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me! I'm a beginner in Android development!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I've fixed it! I called `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` after doing the transaction and it worked! After calling that method I can get the fragment using both `findFragmentById()` and `findFragmentByTag()` methods.

Comment: I'd rather override onAttachFragment and act when the fragment is ready.

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem, or where to put executePendingTransactions().

Comment: @igor-ganapolsky You have to put `executePendingTransactions()`after calling the `.commit()` method of the FragmentTransaction. This forces the system to execute the transaction if it hadn't been done yet.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Add it after the `commit()` and still have a `null` value fragment

Comment: If not using v4-compatibility support library, I think you should do `getFragmentManager()`.executePendingTransactions() rather than `getSupportFragmentManager()`.executePendingTransactions().

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Getting  "FragmentManager is already executing transactions" exception in some cases when calling executePendingTransactions() and some other fragments get messed up.

Comment: No joy.  Still getting null even with `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` placed after the `.commit()` call.

Comment: For those who added executePendingTransactions() and didn't have success, just try adding the Fragment object to your class and reference that in your method that executes the fragment transaction. It's not perfect, but it's a workaround. Make sure you update the Fragment object each time you replace/add a fragment to avoid the object being null...

Comment: I didn't understand why this answer is correct)) It doesn;t help for findFragmentByTag. Where is your full answer and real result?

Answer (score 3):

if you use `setRetainInstance(true)` than you can't use `findFragmentByTag()` in `onCreate` from the Activity. Do it at onResume

see the documentation: [setRetainInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by apologising since I'm still very new myself...

I think the problem may be in the declaration of the fragmentTag static String not properly getting access from the class's instances, just change that line to:

```
private final static String FRAGMENT_TAG = "FRAGMENTB_TAG"; // using uppercase since it's a constant
```

Also, I would be more explicit when declaring instances, for example:

```
public void buttonListener(View v){

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.right_container, new FragmentB(), FRAGMENT_TAG);
    ft.commit();

    FragmentB fragB = (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
    fragB.testView();
}
```

I hope you get this sorted, as I seen this question posted earlier and was surprised that it hadn't got any activity yet.

Also, here are a couple of links to the android documentation on replace:

[Android Training - Replace](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace)

[Android Reference - Replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: It didn't work. The method findFragmentByTag() still returns null despite the changes that you've said me.

Comment: Try replacing the FRAGMENT_TAG with just normal string values then, e.g `ft.replace(R.id.right_container, new FragmentB(), "fragmentB");`

Comment: Neither works. I cant' find an error in my code, and I've tried lots of changes, but I'm still getting a null fragment in the method `findFragmentByTag()`

Comment: @Kenny164  FRAGMENT_TAG is a String constant anyway.  What is the point of replacing it??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and realized that there is a really simple way to fix this. When using a tag please do make sure to add the

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

method so that your Fragment is resumed instead of destroyed as mentioned in the developer guides.

> If you don't call addToBackStack() when you perform a transaction that removes a fragment, then that fragment is destroyed when the transaction is committed and the user cannot navigate back to it. Whereas, if you do call addToBackStack() when removing a fragment, then the fragment is stopped and is later resumed if the user navigates back.

You can find this at the end [of this section](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Transactions).

Every time I tried to reference back to my created Fragment, it turns out it had already been destroyed so I lost about 30 minutes trying to figure out why my Fragment was not being found through a simple `findFragmentByTag();` call.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are adding or replacing the fragment in the proper way

Next statement will add the fragment but it will return null when using getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag):

```
transaction.add(R.id.mainContent, fragment);
```

This way it will work;

```
transaction.add(R.id.mainContent, fragment, tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

We are also seeing this problem but the cause is slightly different. The suggested solution by https://stackoverflow.com/a/21170693/1035008 doesn't work for us.

```
void updateFragment(Fragment newFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // We have these 2 lines extra
    Fragment current = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);           
    if (current != null) { ft.remove(current); }

    ft.replace(R.id.right_container, newFragment, fragmentTag); //Replaces the Fragment C previously in the right_container with a new Fragment B
    ft.commit(); //Finishes the transaction

    //!!HERE THE APP CRASHES (java.lang.NullPointerException = findFragmentByTag returns null
    ((FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag)).testView();
}
```

And after reading the documentation about replace:

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

I realize that the `remove` call was not necessary since it is done by `replace` automatically. So after delete `ft.remove(current)`, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57161814/2914140) to replace and add to BackStack, but set wrong tag:

```
val fragment = { SomeFragment.newInstance() }
fragmentManager?.replaceAndAddToBackStack(R.id.container, fragment, WrongAnotherFragment.TAG)
```

Of course, `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(SomeFragment.TAG)` didn't find `SomeFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

For me probably it was a newbie mistake that I was calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` after I was trying to access the Fragment using `findFragmentByTag`.

I moved `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` up in the order and it started working for me.