# findFragmentByTag() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

**UPDATE:** 
Just to clarify, `show()` is an `android.app.DialogFragment`'s method that I didn't overwrote:

```
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    mDismissed = false;
    mShownByMe = true;
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commit();
}
```

We call the following, where `MyDialog` extends `DialogFragment`:

```
    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), MyDialog.TAG);

    Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyDialog.TAG);
```

But `f` is always `null`. Why?

Comment: have you set fragment with same tag?

Comment: Please post the code on show() method in MyDialog class.

Comment: @HRaval to my understanding, the tag get associated with the fragment by the fragmentManager, as can be seen in the code I've added now.

Comment: you can set tab of fragment when you add it with FragmentTransition...if you havent set it then you cant get it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [findFragmentByTag() returns null after perform a FragmentTransaction using replace() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825600/findfragmentbytag-returns-null-after-perform-a-fragmenttransaction-using-repla)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is simple, `DialogFragment.show` uses `FragmentTransaction.commit` which runs asynchronously. So it will only show up on the next iteration of the main thread. To resolve this just add this one line to your code...

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), MyDialog.TAG);

// Run this line before trying to search for the fragment.
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyDialog.TAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

to add tag with fragment

```
Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container,f,MyDialog.TAG)
    .commit();
```

and to get

```
Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyDialog.TAG);
```

Comment: can you explain how is that different from what `show()` does? that is, how `replace()` is "better" than `add()`

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack

Answer (score -1):

FindFragmentByTag returns fragment if found or null otherwise.

Comment: Sure. the question is why can't it find a recently added fragment.