# unable to destroy activity can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState when back button is pressed

Tags: java, android

You can find my project archive [here](http://www.speedyshare.com/JXATS/ThesGuideProject.rar).

I would be grateful to anyone who will give my problem a try
press **"Text" => "Cursor Adapter" => "Museums" then select any of the museums**. The navigation between tabs does not causes problems but when either the `"Menu Fragment" Tab` or the `"On Map Fragment"` is selected and i press the back button the following problem occurs:

```
07-28 16:06:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(21839): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Unable to destroy activity {com.example.thesguideproject/com.example.thesguideproject.Test}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-h, or http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: I have read all the related solutions but i couldn't figure out what i am doing wrong

Comment: i think i solved the problem, i removed this code: Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment)); 
  FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.remove(fragment);
  //ft.detach(fragment);
        ft.commit();   from onDestroyView to onPause method

Comment: Atul O Holic thanks a lot for the second link you suggested