# Migrating from appcompat-v7:21.0.1 to appcompat-v7:23.1.1 now im sad

Tags: android, appcompat-v7-toolbar

Migrating from appcompat-v7:21.0.1 to appcompat-v7:23.1.1 **OnPrepareOptionsMenu is not called**, now im sad.

Before I migrated the support library there was no issue at all. Then between 2-3 builds/runs(If i add code or add resources) menu suddenly disappears with no errors run-time nor compile time.  I `LOG` `onPrepareOptionsMenu` calls and as expected it doesn't get called. I tried going back to 21.0.1 but i encountered much more fearsome issues. In-short I cannot go back.

What I always do is do

> Build->Clean

And It would show my menu back again.

If this would be helpful I will post what I deem relevant:

```
dependencies {
    //    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/mqttv3-1.0.0.jar')
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
        // exclusion is not neccessary, but generally a good idea.
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    // Google Activity Recognition
    // Google Maps
    // Google+'
    // Google Account Login
    dependencies {
        compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:0.7.4@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
    }
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile files('libs/dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar')
    testCompile files('libs/dexmaker-1.0.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.4.2'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.andreabaccega:android-form-edittext:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.shehabic.droppy:Droppy:0.2.5.1@aar'
    compile 'com.andreabaccega:android-form-edittext:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.anrwatchdog:anrwatchdog:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.romainpiel.shimmer:library:1.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.1.9@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:1.1.8'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.7'
    //    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    //        compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.+@aar') {
    //            transitive = true
    //        }
    //        compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.+@aar') {
    //            transitive = true
    //        }
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
    compile project(':commons')
    compile project(':core')

}
```

My `MainMenu` which extends to `AppCompatActivity`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // omitted some butterknife injections
    if(mToolbar != null ){
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }     

    mDrawerToggler = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this ,mDrawer , mToolbar , R.string.drawer_open , R.string.drawer_close ){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            invalidateOptionsMenu();


       }


        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

            invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }
    };

    mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggler);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    final int currentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(Constants.CURRENT_POSITION);
    selectItem(currentIndex);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(Constants.CURRENT_POSITION, mListView.getSelectedItemPosition());
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(mLeftDrawer);
    hideMenuItems(menu, !drawerOpen);
    Log.w(TAG , "onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)" );
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void hideMenuItems(Menu menu, boolean visible){
    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){
        menu.getItem(i).setVisible(visible);
    }
}


private void selectItem(int position){

    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    Fragment frag = null;
    // omitted some fragment selection process
    if(frag != null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, frag)
                //.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK)
                // commitAllowingStateLoss() instead of commit()
                // this is a known bug on API > 11
                // http://stackoverflow.com/a/10261449/3974048
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
    if( position != Constants.A_LOGOUT  || position != Constants.S_LOGOUT ) {
        mListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mDrawer.closeDrawer(mLeftDrawer);
    mCurrentPosition = position;
}
```

issue in google :
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=1&start=0&num=100&q=onPrepareOptionsMenu&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=172133

My post:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=5&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=199405#makechanges

Im currently using gradle 2.0.0.alhpa6. latest android studio from canary.

Comment: Are you overriding the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method?

Comment: yes, most of my fragments override it.