# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, runtimeexception, onresume

Following is My Log Repost

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.maruticourier.android/com.marutideliver.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3069)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3098)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
>   Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1365)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1383)
>          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:636)
>          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:615)
>          at com.marutideliver.activity.MainActivity.selectItem(MainActivity.java:485)
>          at com.marutideliver.activity.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:810)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1198)
>          at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5620)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3098)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Comment: write onResume method here

Comment: where i write onResume method ??

Comment: here. in the question.put your code

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It's may be because of not overwrite onResume() method you must overwite and restore your save-instance that previous store

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in support package.To avoid this you can use following during fragment transaction.

```
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

If you google it you'll find many good answers to it.For more reference and alternate methods see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa).Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a non-static subclass (I'm guessing it's a fragment) that your activity fails to instantiate every time it is resumed. In case you have such subclass, just make it static.

Comment: thank you for your answer but if i make subclass to static than many error occur because i use non-static method in this fragment class so its not work

Answer (score 0):

It's may be because of using `add()` method many times with public method like

```
 public void beginTransaction(ID id, Bundle bundle)
```

**Avoid using**

```
fragmentmanager.begintransaction().add
```

**each time,**

**Use this too for replacing**

```
fragmentmanager.begintransaction().replace(r.id.frame_container, fragment).commit()
```