# IllegalStateException while showing DialogFragment after back from AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment, illegalstateexception

I am starting a FragmentActivity from a custom DialogFragment and after I come back the original Activity and try to open the dialog again I get:

> IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

I don't understand why is it happening, if I dismiss the dialog from the original activity than I can show it again as many times as I want, but if I start a new Activity from the DialogFragment after that I cannot show any dialog again because I get the exception.

Here is my code, this method is in my DialogFragment:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3){
     mSearchLocationType = position;
     switch(position){
         case PSL_CURRENT_POSITION: // I can show the dialog again after this.
             break;
         case PSL_MAP_POINT:
             Intent selectMapPoint = new Intent(parentActivity, SelectMapPointActivity.class);     
             selectMapPoint.putExtra(SelectMapPointFragment.EXTRA_SELECTED_POS, mSearchLocation);
             parentActivity.startActivityForResult(selectMapPoint, REQ_MAP_POINT); 
             // After returning this Activity and trying to show ANY DialogFragment the app crashes.
             break;
         case PSL_ADDRESS:
             Intent selectAddress = new Intent(parentActivity, SelectAddressActivity.class);
             parentActivity.startActivity(selectAddress); // Also from this Activity, makes no difference.
             break;
      }
      dismiss();
 }
```

I am showing the dialog like:

```
if(!selectPoiAroundDialog.isVisible())
    selectPoiAroundDialog.show(parentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "mSelectPoiCategoryDialog");
```

What I have tried already:

- Override the show() method of the DialogFragment and use this code to show the dialog:

  > FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
  >   ft.add(this, tag);
  >   ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
- Debug the app and check if all the lifecycle methods are called, but it seems normal to me, each of the times the onDestroyView() method of the DialogFragment is called.
- Override the show() and onDismiss() method of the DialogFragment and track if it is shown or not.

This is a corporate app and has a bad design, so the class which I am trying to modify (where I am showing the dialog) is not child of Activity or Fragment. ´parentActivity´ is accessed by a static method of the application class, but I am sure that it has the right Activity. Do you think this can cause the problem?

**EDIT:**
The full stacktrace is when I useing commitAllowStateLoss():

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1515)
 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:621)
 at com.mycompany.dialog.GTDialog.show(GTDialog.java:174)
 at com.mycompany.fragment.content.SearchOfflinePOIContent$2.onClick(SearchOfflinePOIContent.java:250)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21209)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

- I also tried to override the `onSaveInstanceState()` method, it didn't helped.

**EDIT2:**
The original stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)
at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:139)
at com.mycompany.dialog.GTDialog.show(GTDialog.java:174)
at com.mycompany.fragment.content.SearchOfflinePOIContent$1.onClick(SearchOfflinePOIContent.java:197)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21209)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

If I override the show() method and try to commit the fragment with `commitAllowingStateLoss()` than I get the first exception.

Comment: Could you please post the full error log?

Comment: Did you  override the `onSaveInstanceState` method? If not, then override it. And don't make the call to `super()` on the `onSaveInstanceState` method. This may help

Comment: Also please check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit#27854077

Comment: @Shoshi I added the full stacktrace to the question, I don't call popbackstack :(. I tried to override the onSaveInstanceState method, but nothing changed :(.

Comment: have you tried replaching the `parentActivity` to `getActivity()`? i mean something like `selectPoiAroundDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "mSelectPoiCategoryDialog");`

Comment: and did you see that now the error is `IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed` not `IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: @Shoshi I see the difference, trying to reproduce the original exception.. Because the class is not a child of Activity, it does not have `getActivity()` method

Comment: @Shoshi I editet my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. When the app quit from an Activity it didn't remove the reference of it from `parentActivity`, so when I tried to show the dialog again I gave a reference of the destroyed activity.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: glad you find out the problem (y)

Comment: thanks mate :D best wishes for your proramming life :D

Comment: But how did you fix it?

Comment: I have removed the reference of the destroyed Activity from parentActivity variable.