# Android Fragment transaction in background

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an application with fragments. It has a JavaScript Interface, which is called in the Main Activity and has fragment replacing logic. When application is in foreground everything works OK, but when the application is in background, fragment transaction replace doesn't work. When I return to my application, I still see the old fragment and don't see the new one.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void beginCall(String toast) {
    FragmentTransaction fTrans;
    taskFragment = TaskFragment.newInstance(toast,"");
    fTrans =    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fTrans.replace(R.id.frgmCont, taskFragment);
    fTrans.commit();
}
```

What is wrong? Why the fragment transaction doesn't work in background?

Comment: Call beginCall() method from your Activty's onResume() also.

Comment: @Drv, it will break the app logic if I do so

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some time I've found the answer: it's impossible to perform a fragment transaction after onStop, it will result in java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState. I wasn't getting that Exception as JavascriptInterface was performed in a separate thread. When I forced my code to run in Main thread, I got that error. So I need to implement a different logic, also using some of Activity Life-cycle methods, or to switch to multiple activities logic. Hope my answer will help anyone.

Answer (score 5):

Some use cases or architectures might require to trigger fragment transactions while app is in background.

We created following extension function:

```
fun FragmentTransaction.commitWhenStarted(lifecycle: Lifecycle) {
   lifecycle.addObserver(object : LifecycleObserver {
      @OnLifecycleEvent(value = Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
      fun onStart() {
        lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
        commit()
      }
   })
}
```

Use it just like any other version of commit, commitNow, commitAllowingStateLoss.
If the activity state is already at least started the observer will be called directly and the fragment transaction is executed. The lifecycle can be taken from activity or from fragment if the transaction is executed on a childFragmentManager

```
transaction.commitWhenStarted(lifecycle)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 FragRecordSongList FragRecordSongList = new FragRecordSongList();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.addToBackStack(FragRecordSongList.class.getName());
        ft.replace(R.id.fragContainer, FragRecordSongList, FragRecordSongList.class.getName());
        ft.commit();
```

Try this may be help you

Answer (score 1):

@lilienberg commented a great solution for fragment transactions. If you are using the navigation component you can use something like this:

```
fun NavController.resumedNavigation(lifecycle: Lifecycle, destination: Int) {
    if(lifecycle.currentState.isAtleast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)){
       //App is resumed, continue navigation.
       navigate(destination)
    } else {
         //When app is resumed, remove observer and navigate to destination/
         lifecycle.addObserver(object: LifecycleObserver {
              @OnLifecycleEvent(value = Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
              fun onResume() {
                  lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
                  navigate(destination)
              }
         })
     }
  }
```

You can call this function from your Activity or Fragment like this:

```
findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment).resumedNavigation(
                lifecycle, R.id.my_navigation_action)
```