# fragment.commit() gives illegalStateException, cannot perform after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 activities, A and B. Activity A consists of a fragment. For the notification click, I'm using TaskStackBuilder, calling nextIntent as B which has parentActivity as A. For the nextIntent, I'm setting Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

The scenario is, B activity is in foreground, notification arrives and you click on it, Activity A gets destroyed, Activity B loads from onCreate. If I go back, Activity A's onCreate gets loaded, but for fragment commit call, I'm getting the following crash.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this
>   action after onSaveInstanceState
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
>          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
>          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)

Here's how I'm committing the fragment

```
  EgFragment fragment = new EgFragment();  
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.view, fragment).commit();
```

Any help to overcome this scenario.....

Comment: Show the code please. Did you mean `FragmentTransaction.commit` and not `fragment.commit`? :)

Comment: I've edited the question with the commit code

Comment: Try committing your fragment transaction allowing state loss

Comment: @Eenvincible : It gives another crash saying that fragment cannot be committed when activity is destroyed.

Comment: Wait, can you just start the activity without saying FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK?

Comment: @Eenvincible : Then a new instance of the task will be created regardless of what is in the foreground.

Comment: I remember having this issue before but it is gone from my head!!

Comment: @Eenvincible : I'm cracking my head on this from past 2 days. Could not get it to work...

Comment: Look at this; I remember doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit

Comment: With that as the answer, I'm getting this
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. In FragmentManager, there are two booleans, mStateSaved and mDestroyed. In onStop, mSavedState will be set to true. In OnDestroy, mDestroyed will be set to true, but mStateSaved is not set to false.

Now, when Activity B is launched from Activity A, A's onStop sets mStateSaved to true. In B, when notification click occurs with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. Both activities onDestroy will be called. Now, the onCreate gets called which makes the mStateSaved as false but after this, if we use getSupportFragmentManager and commit the fragment, mStateSaved will be true.

I think getSupportFragmentManager() is returning previous instance's manager where mStateSaved was true.

Now i do not know how to solve this.