# FormsAppCompatActivity causing issue when using Media Plugin

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms app and I have implemented Media plugin to takePicture. It was working fine with my old theme in Xamarin Android "FormsApplicationActivity" but when I inherited MyActivity with "FormsAppCompatActivity" I am facing issues.

Actually after taking picture it is navigating me back to my start page.
I found that this is bug and have been reported here

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36907

I have updated my xamarin forms to 2.3.4 but still the issue exists.
Does any one fixed this issue?

Comment: In a few comments up from yours there is a link to another SO question which should hold the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397431/xamarin-forms-popasync-crash/41897674#41897674

Comment: @GeraldVersluis thanks for quick reply. I tried that solution but its not working for me.