# Getting exception ...Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

App throws below exception at random time and in radom devices. I am not getting when it is coming actually. I just got too many crash reports on fabric of this.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.modifiesAlpha(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.dump(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.dump(Unknown Source)
       at com.example.MyAcvitity.ShowDialogBox(Unknown Source)
       at com.example.MyAcvitity.ShowDialogBox(Unknown Source)
       at com.example.MyAcvitity$3.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5351)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
```

I have tried..

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //No call for super(). Bug on API Level > 11.
        // override this method to avoide (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState) this exception

    }
```

but still its giving the same exception.

MyActivity contains fragments.
How do I come out from this?

Comment: Please see this question it is similar to your problem.It might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit

Comment: @Umair I have seen that and already taken the action as per the accepted answer.. Please check that I have tried that thing as mentioned above, by overriding onSaveInstanceState() method without calling super. but it doesn't fix this issue.

Comment: Have the same exception. Do you find a fix?