# App is crashed on first time after granting write permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions, bottom-sheet

I struct at first page, I am not able to open Dialog soon after permission granted(Write). First time I asked Permission and I granted Permission,in onRequestPermissionsResult() I opened Dialog, here App is closed with Unfortunately APP has crashed issue. When reopen App the issue not here, It is running normally.I got issue in Monitor
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`
 .I Searched lot but different answers I've seen.Please help me ,I am not getting why app is crashed first time.
**Here is my code:**

```
 llAddPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!tvAddPhotoOrNext.getText().toString().equals("Next")) { // When Image not gone selected
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        //First checking if the app is already having the permission
                        if (isReadStorageAllowed()) {
                            //If permission is already having then showing the toast
                            Toast.makeText(AddUserProfilePic.this, "You already have the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //Existing the method with return
                            showFourButtonsBSDialog();
                        }else {
                            //If the app has not the permission then ask for the permission
                            checkPermissions();
                        }
                    } else
                        showFourButtonsBSDialog();
                } else {        // When image gone selected.
                    mSetProfilePicByAPI();
                }

            }
        });
```

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void checkPermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PICKIMAGE);
    } else {

    }
}
```

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PICKIMAGE:
            //If permission is granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Displaying a toast
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                showFourButtonsBSDialog();
            } else {
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
}
```

```
   /* BottomSheetDialog */
private void showFourButtonsBSDialog() {

    MoreOptionsDialogFragment mTBFragment  = new MoreOptionsDialogFragment();   // ThreeButtonsFragment
    Bundle mTextNamesArgs = new Bundle(); //Send buttons names
    mTextNamesArgs.putStringArray("buttons_names",new String[]{"Take Photo","Choose from library",
    "Photo from Facebook","Photo from Instagram"});
    mTBFragment.setArguments(mTextNamesArgs);
    mTBFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),mTBFragment.getTag());
}
```

```
 private boolean isReadStorageAllowed() {
    //Getting the permission status
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    //If permission is granted returning true
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return true;
    //If permission is not granted returning false
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are your compile SDK and target SDK versions? Make sure them to be 23 or higher.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: minSdkVersion is 19 and
        targetSdkVersion 25.

Comment: could you try the solution given in the following answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10261449/8109872