# "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" with Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

I check the connected Internet and if it false, then call method openAsRoot in onCreate() Activity

```
private void openAsRoot(Fragment fragment) {
    manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container_main, fragment).commit();
}
```

it is perfect, but when I open the settings to turn on the Internet and then go back to my application  - showed error in

```
    @Override
protected void onRestart() {
    if (isConnected()) {
        openAsRoot(myFragment);
    }
    super.onRestart();
}
```

Error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"

How can I fix this ?

Comment: This is a pretty common issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting exception "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469082/getting-exception-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsa)