# IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState with onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

I am new to Android development. I got an issue. I tried the last couple of hour but I can't figure out this. if so I got a popular question. [IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState with ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit) but failed because of the lack of Android development experience.

Here is code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                MyCustomDialogFragment newPopup = new MyCustomDialogFragment();
                newPopup.setMyClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                newPopup.show(fragmentManager, "CashReceivePopup");  
          } 
       }
   }
```

Here is the error:

> 01-04 05:08:57.010 13609-13609/com.nazmul.aznazgame.bitlife
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 01-04 05:08:57.068
>   13609-13609/com.nazmul.aznazgame.bitlife E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.nazmul.aznazgame.bitlife, PID: 13609
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=4, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras)
>   }} to activity
>   {com.nazmul.aznazgame.bitlife/com.nazmul.aznazgame.bitlife.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3574)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2053)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2079)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:678)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:632)
>           at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:143)
>           at com.nazmul.aznazgame.bitlife.MainActivity.showEducationDialog(MainActivity.java:1716)
>           at com.nazmul.aznazgame.bitlife.MainActivity.manageActivity(MainActivity.java:604)
>           at com.nazmul.aznazgame.bitlife.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:580)
>           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)  01-04
>   05:08:59.825 13609-13651/com.nazmul.aznazgame.bitlife
>   I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete:
>   5C2EEA4F018E-0001-3529-63E978D09744 01-04 05:08:59.955
>   13609-13609/com.nazmul.aznazgame.bitlife I/Process: Sending signal.
>   PID: 13609 SIG: 9

Comment: What version of the Support Library are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake which Library version you looking to check? I do not get you

Comment: @ianhanniballake i am using `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;` is it your answer?

Comment: Support Library Means `android.support` library . You can find it in your `build.gradle` file . Although this exception can be thrown when OS has killed your previous `Activity`.

Comment: I mean the version of the Support Library dependencies in your `build.gradle` - something like `28.0.0` or `27.1.0`, etc.

Comment: @ianhanniballake here is my `build.gradle (module:app)` https://gist.github.com/nazmulkp/7af9f875863b55630dd45fd92773ced9

Comment: @ianhanniballake @ianhanniballake here is my `build.gradle(Project:bitlife-android)` https://gist.github.com/nazmulkp/b77e51fd28989af6effba6ee215e6a87

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must call `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` before doing any FragmentTransactions in your `onActivityResult()` method as that call is what 'unlocks' the FragmentManager and notes that you are in a valid state to do FragmentTransactions.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Add this line
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // This all remains the same
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                MyCustomDialogFragment newPopup = new MyCustomDialogFragment();
                newPopup.setMyClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                newPopup.show(fragmentManager, "CashReceivePopup");  
          } 
       }
   }
```

Comment: This is not related to this question. for information: I used `onActivityResult` to send `data` to previous activity but I seem it' take too much time to `transaction activity`. is there anything like iOS (`delegate` for sending data back `ViewController`) that is made faster but in android anything else. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem. You have 2 options how to deal with this issue.

1. you can override the `show()` method and put its content inside a `try-catch` block
2. You display the dialog in the followong way

   ```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyDialog d = new MyDialog();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(d, "dialog");
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
   ```