# Fix Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState after onActivityResult without UI issues

Tags: android, onactivityresult, android-mvvm, android-savedstate

I have noticed some crashes in onActivityResult after receiving results from activity, which was launched in third party SDK. I personally use singleActivity with multiple fragments and I did not run into this issue. The question is: how should I **safely perform fragment transaction after onActivityResult?**

After some testing we found that our manual locale changing did not worked after stateLoss, here is our method:

```
// here I provide specific locale

private fun setupLocale(locale: String) {
            val config = this.resources.configuration
            val locale = Locale(locale)
            Locale.setDefault(locale)
            config.locale = locale
            this.baseContext.resources.updateConfiguration(config,
                    this.baseContext.resources.displayMetrics)

    }
```

I call this method in onCreate, but it does not **get triggered after state loss**...

It seems, that commitAllowingStateLoss() creates weird bugs, as noted in documentation... How should I fix this issue? The two main questions:

1. How should I safely perform fragment transaction in **onActivityResult, without commitAllowingStateLoss()**?
2. If this is not possible, how should I restore my state after state loss occurred following MVVM pattern and make sure that **UI is kept in check**? Will my VM survive? If not, should I pass c**ustomLocale in bundle** and retrieve it in activity?

**EDIT**

Perhaps my problem was that I did not had this line in my onActivityResult?:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
```

I found similar question on [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033509/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit):

This is how I notify my VM, from onActivityResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_VERIFICATION) {
                viewModel.openFragmentNr3(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

​

```
//VM
  val addFragmentNr3 = SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>()

  fun openFragmentNr3(shouldOpen:Boolean)
    {
        addFragmentNr3.value = shouldOpen
    }
```

Then I observe it regularly in my single Activity :)

Comment: Can you include your `onActivityResult()` method?

Comment: I have edited my question and provided possible cause of issue :)

Comment: You have to call `super.onActivityResult()`.