# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState using a BottomsheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

I am using BottomsheetDialogFragment and recently getting crash reports on crashlytics, the stacktrace is -

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this
>   action after onSaveInstanceState
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2044)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2067)
>          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:680)
>          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:634)
>          at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:205)
>          at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(DialogFragment.java:171)
>          at com.khaalijeb.inkdrops.ListBanks.onSuccessResponse(ListBanks.java:322)
>          at com.khaalijeb.inkdrops.App.onSuccessResponse(App.java:800)
>          at com.olive.upi.OliveUpiManager.onSuccessResponse(Unknown Source:970)
>          at com.olive.upi.transport.d$33.onResponse(Unknown Source:16)
>          at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

I don't know what caused this error since it is not happening in some device and not all of them. Did anyone face this problem earlier and how to overcome it?

I have tested this particular code 1000 times but never got one but in the production world, I am getting this error in around 2 3 devices.

How to call **commitAllowingStateLoss();**? will this fixed the problem?

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10261449/284308

Comment: What's causing this? did my Activity is being restored again and bottomsheetfragemnt is not able to get restored?

Comment: Hi @AmanVerma I am also facing the same issue in the production world. Have you found the solution? If yes, then please share it.

Comment: FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        BottomSheetDialogFragment Fragment = new BottomSheetDialogFragment();
        transaction.add(Fragment, "loading");
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

Answer (score 5):

There is `BottomsheetDialogFragment#dismissAllowingStateLoss` [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment?hl=en#dismissallowingstateloss) in the material library that will allow you to fix this problem