# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState in android

Tags: android, kotlin

> How can I Add a check to prevent this error

**I am getting the error in this code:**

```
private fun clearFragmentsFromContainer() {
    if(supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount>0) {
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
    }
}
```

**Error on the line:**

```
supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

**Log**:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2080)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2106)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStack(FragmentManager.java:832)
        at com.caring2u.organizer.ui.activities.screen.ActSummaryEvent.clearFragmentsFromContainer(ActSummaryEvent.kt:524)
        at com.caring2u.organizer.ui.activities.screen.ActSummaryEvent.onClickEventTabs(ActSummaryEvent.kt:466)
        at com.caring2u.organizer.ui.activities.screen.ActSummaryEvent.dataEventsList(ActSummaryEvent.kt:162)
        at com.caring2u.organizer.network.retrofit.retrofitTasks.RetroEventsSummary$initiate$1.onResponse(RetroEventsSummary.kt:62)
```

Comment: Where exactly you calling `clearFragmentsFromContainer()`? Add code for calling .

Comment: I have loaded 5 fragments to a container. I am trying to call this method in activity to clear all the fragments in container before starting a new fragment

Comment: I asked Where you call this method not why you calling it . Add code .. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the fragment stack after `onPause` as can be seen from the log.

You can either use `FragmentManger.commitAllowingStateLoss` or be sure to not call this method after `onPause`

Comment: For all the fragment transcactions i use `FragmentManger.commitAllowingStateLoss`

Comment: in general, it's a bad idea to use it. you should try not to commit anything after onPause

Answer (score 0):

To remove all fragments in a container please use below code

```
for (Fragment fragment:getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
    if (fragment instanceof NavigationDrawerFragment) {
        continue;
    }
    else if (fragment!=null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your fragment transaction is committing **after** `onSavedInstanceState()` callback. That means that your activity is stopping and you're adding your fragment in a state that cannot be saved. Actually, during onSavedInstanceState() call Android takes a snapshot of your activity state, this means that if you commit a transaction after the state it's saved the transaction won't be remembered as it was never recorded. From the user point of view that will result in a UI state loss. 
Instead of using `commitAllowingStateLoss` you should understand if you're calling your `clearFragmentsFromContainer` method from an asynchronous method, in that case probably you should simply move your transaction from the async method.

More about "commit state loss":

- [AndroidDesignPatterns.com](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)
- [Elye](https://medium.com/@elye.project/handling-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-d4ee8b630066) on Medium

In order to understand if your activity has already called onSaveInstanceState() method, you might think to place a flag inside onSaveInstanceState callback, resetting the flag in the dual method onRestoreInstanceState, something like:

```kotlin
val saveInstanceStateCalled = false

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveInstanceStateCalled = true

    }
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    saveInstanceStateCalled = false

}
```

Then you can check the flag before calling `clearFragmentsFromContainer`

Answer (score 0):

**I solved this using the code**

```
if (!fragmentManager.isStateSaved()) {
           if(supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount>0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
    }
}
```