# android IllegalStateException during onBackPressed

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I have a very weird expception happening on my app.

I overwrote the `onBackPressed` of some of my activities in order to show an intertitial ad. the code is very simple

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        if (showIntertitialAd())
            //pseudocodehere
           show ad
            ... on close -> super.onBackPressed();

        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

however, somehow im gettng `IllegalStateException` in some cases here is the stacktrace

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1413)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:576)
       at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2507)
       at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.access$001(ComponentActivity.java:53)
       at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$1.run(ComponentActivity.java:77)
       at androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed(OnBackPressedDispatcher.java:197)
       at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onBackPressed(ComponentActivity.java:314)
       at com.tomatedigital.adinjector.AdsAppCompatActivity.access$001(AdsAppCompatActivity.java:50)
       at com.tomatedigital.adinjector.AdsAppCompatActivity$OnBackPressededReward.onRewarded(AdsAppCompatActivity.java:542)
       at com.tomatedigital.adinjector.listener.InterstitialAdListener.onAdClosed(InterstitialAdListener.java:40)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzuf.onAdClosed(zzuf.java:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzvp.zza(zzvp.java:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgk.onTransact(zzgk.java:13)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
       at fj.b(fj.java:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.ag.a(ag.java:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzk.n(zzk.java:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.aq.n(aq.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.g.D(g.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.aq.D(aq.java:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.k.n(k.java:5)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.k.m(k.java:6)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.k.e(k.java:3)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.client.b.a(b.java:13)
       at fk.onTransact(fk.java:4)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgi.zza(zzgi.java:21)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzapi.onPause(zzapi.java:17)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onPause(AdActivity.java:40)
       at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6356)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1334)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3388)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3336)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap13(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1372)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: Check if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your activity is sometimes paused when you call `onBackPressed()` because of the ad, even though you have the "on close" pseudo code. `onBackPressed()` can't be called when activity is on pause.

Have you tried using `finish()` in this case? If your intention is to close the current activity/fragment, that could work as well.

Answer (score -1):

To Avoid crash on back press just modify the code.
As well as you can get the actual exception on the log and can modify your code.
However, It will not crash your application.

```
    public void onBackPressed() {

    try{
    if (showIntertitialAd())
                //pseudocodehere
               show ad
                ... on close -> super.onBackPressed();

            else
                super.onBackPressed();
    }catch(Exception ex){
    Log.e(ex.localizedmessage)
super.onBackPressed();
    }
        }
```