# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState crash on many devices

Tags: android, crashlytics, production

I am getting this crash on many users in my application which is on the play store. I don't understand the reason because logcat showing in crashlytics is weird.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1882)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1905)
   at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:688)
   at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:646)
   at com.jojoy.delegate.JojoyInstallerActivity.switchContent(JojoyInstallerActivity.java:78)
   at com.jojoy.delegate.JojoyInstallerActivity.access$000(JojoyInstallerActivity.java:35)
   at com.jojoy.delegate.JojoyInstallerActivity$FragmentHandler.handleMessage(JojoyInstallerActivity.java:139)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Here, what is this JojoyInstallerActivity? I don't understand totally. because I am not using it in my whole application. Even I tried to search on google but didn't find a single piece about that.

Comment: Have you checked solution on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-wit by any chance?

Comment: Are you sure you google searched for 'joyjoy android'? Because there are a lot of relevant results about a 'free APK downloader'.

Comment: @Faisal It's not related to my issue.

Comment: @ianhanniballake It's a third-party app that is not included in my application.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I got the same stacktrace sent to my play console today. One user installed a modded/cracked version of your app which then started the JojoyInstallerActivity which should have installed their jojoy app...but failed because it crashed. So really nothing you should bother about.

Comment: @JayTee There are a few users around 20 to 30. who got a such an error.

Comment: @SagarMaiyad Yeah, all those searched for a free version of your app, and installed a modded version of your app that contains that adware which fails to install. I'm not sure what so hard to understand. That's not an app version someone installed from the playstore, but from a 3rd party page which injected adware into regular apps trying to trick people installing their JoJo app. Just ignore those bug reports.