# How to replace last element of back stack?

Tags: android

How to add fragment to back stack, but replacing last history ? Example below.

```
[frag1].addToBackStack(null) 
     -> [frag2].addToBackStack(null) 
         -> [frag3].addToBackStack(null) // need here replace frag2 in history (back button get to frag1)
```

Comment: I just read the source code of support.v4.FragmentManager. Seems there's no way to do it.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772921/how-to-pop-back-stack-for-activity-with-multiple-fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); to remove frag2 to the backstack and getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(...) to change the frag3 by other.

Hope it helps you!