# How to add back pressed button in diffeent fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I using BottomNavigationView with 3 main Fragment, like `Fragment [A], [B], [C]`.
and `Fragment [A]` is default fragment, if `Fragment [B]` or `[C]` press `back button` must return to `Fragment A`. In `fragment [B]`, I add button to get Another fragment just call it `Fragment [D]`, but if in Fragment D i pressed back button app return into `fragment [A]`.

So How to return into `Fragment [B]` when `fragment [D]` is press back button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pop back stack for Activity with multiple Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772921/how-to-pop-back-stack-for-activity-with-multiple-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with fragments stack. Implement onBackPressed() in activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Work with fragments stack...

    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();    
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no onBackPressed function from Fragment.
That's why you should define callback interface for backPressed event.

```
    public interface IFragment {
        boolean onBackPressed();
    }
```

Then, you should implement your fragment [A], [B], [C], [D].

```
    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        return true;
    }
```

And you should handle it in your host activity of Fragments.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();

        boolean handled = false;
        for(Fragment f : fragments) {
            if(f instanceof IFragment) {
                handled = ((IFragment) f).onBackPressed();
                if(handled) {
                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    for(String name : fragmentNames) {
                        fm.popBackStack(name, 0);
                    }
                    fm.beginTransaction().commit();
                }
            }
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

I just implemented the code and let you know what you have to know.
Good luck.