# How can I do with android Fragment backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have four Fragment A B C D.When I perform jumping from A to B and B to C and C to D. How can I get the result of D to B when I press back key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5984892/1160282

Check this

Comment: Do you want to send information back to B from D or do you just want to show B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FragmentD:**

Create an interface in FragmentD.

```
OnBackListener mback;
    public interface OnBackListener {
        public void onBackClicked();
}

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        try {
            mback = (OnBackListener ) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnBackListener");
        }
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }


public void methodCall()
    {
      mback.onBackClicked()
    }
```

then

**Parent Activity**

Implement the OnBackListener interface that we created in FragmentD.

```
 public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnBackListener {


// overriding OnBackListener interface method
        @Override
            public void onBackClicked() {

                  //calling fragmentb
            }   

    //Backkey event
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
            fragmentd.methodCall();
        }

        }
```

In the way, you will get result of fragmentD to fragmentB.

Comment: I want to use back key to perform jumping from D to B,however the back key was controllered by FragmentActivity.So the interface call onBackClicked() won't be done.

Comment: Hi Androider, is there any easier way if I want the result of D to C when I press back key?