# popBackStack() after addToBackStack does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments

My project contains two fragment :

- FragmentA : the fragment loaded by default when the app starts
- FragmentB : replace the `fragmentA` when a click on a button is done.

This is the XML of my main view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:name="fragmentA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I wish to replace the `FragmentA` by the `FragmentB`, I use this code :

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new FragmentB());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This code works fine. My FragmentA is replaced by the new `FragmentB`. But when a click is done on the back button, I wish replace the `FragmentB` by the `FragmentA` by using `popBackStackImmediate()`.

This is the code I use:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
    boolean done = getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

The function `popBackStackImmediate` return always false and the `FragmentB` still in foreground.

Why the FragmentA does not replace the FragmentB when I call `popBackStackImmediate` ? Is anybody has an idea to solve my problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Avoid using back stacks! it doesn't really help with the overall efficiency! use plain replace() or even better remove/add every time you want to navigate! Check my post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802141/is-this-the-right-way-to-clean-up-fragment-back-stack-when-leaving-a-deeply-nest/26093368#26093368

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You use the `getSupportedFragmentManager()` to replace `FragmentA` by `FragmentB`. But you call `popBackStack()` on the `getFragmentManager()`.

If you are adding the Fragments to the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` you also have to call `popBackStack()` on the same `FragmentManager`.

This code should solve the problem:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
    boolean done = getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

Comment: In my case I was using supportedFragmentManager in the activity and childFragmentManager in B to open C and when I had press backButton in C it was sending me to A instead of B

Answer (score 7):

You should call

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

after performing all operations such as add(), remove(), and replace() and Just before commit(). Only then this transaction will be added to backstack. Only then you will be able to return to previous fragment state with *Back* button. Details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is you're mixing `Fragment` and methods from the support library.

If you are using the support library, make sure:

- your `Activity` extends from the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`
- your `Fragment` extends from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
- use `getSupportFragmentManager()` to get the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

Your code in the `Activity` would be:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
   getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

Please be aware that if you would like to get the `FragmentManager` from the `Fragment` code, you have to use the [getFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager%28%29) method, as explained in the documentation (probably that's the cause of some confusion if you don't have much experience).

If you are not using the support library:

- your `Activity` extends from the `android.app.Activity`
- your `Fragment` extends from `android.app.Fragment`
- use `getFragmentManager()` to get the `android.app.FragmentManager`

Your code would be:

```
if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
   getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

`fragmentTransaction.commit();` is not necessary in both cases, so remove it.

Also, please call `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);` just before the `commit` but after the other operations.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest using the fragment replacement with Tag  to produce the same result .

Add the fragment B  to activity with tag

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new FragmentB(),"TAG_B");
```

Fragment A -> Fragment B [onBackPressed] -->Fragment A
Override the onBackPressed() in the Activity files where ,

// check for fragment B and you are viewing  fragment B

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG_B")!=null)  
{
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new FragmentA(),"TAG_A");
}
```

addToBackStack("TAG") and popBackStackImmediate("TAG") always revert to fragment condition  without any data in the UI right before fragment is created or added to activity !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the order of your code. Here are two things you need to pay attention to.

1. You need to use addToBackStack() after your adding,
   replacing fragment. Then commmit()
2. Then popBackStackImmediate can reverse the operation and it is working. I hope it solves the problem. I know it is an old post but I
   do encounter a similar problem and wish this update can help others. Below should be the correct order:

   `FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction   =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

   ```
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new FragmentB());

   fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

   fragmentTransaction.commit();
   ```

Answer (score -1):

If you are Struggling with addToBackStack() and popBackStack() then simply use

```
FragmentTransaction ft =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment(), "Home");
ft.commit();`
```

In your Activity In OnBackPressed() find out fargment by tag and then do your stuff

```
Fragment home = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Home");

if (home instanceof HomeFragment && home.isVisible()) {
    // do you stuff
}
```

For more Information https://github.com/DattaHujare/NavigationDrawer I never use addToBackStack() for handling fragment.