# How to clear previous Fragment stack in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In android activity we are using to clean top activity  `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` how to achieve this fragment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this the right way to clean-up Fragment back stack when leaving a deeply nested stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802141/is-this-the-right-way-to-clean-up-fragment-back-stack-when-leaving-a-deeply-nest)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
private void clearBackStack() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager
                .getBackStackEntryAt(0);
        manager.popBackStack(first.getId(),
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {   

    fm.popBackStack();
}
```