# No view found for id when popping backstack without adding to backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I am working on an Android app and have encountered an error involving Fragments and FragmentTransactions. I have created an example app to demonstrate the problem. Here is what I am doing:

1. `add` `Fragment1` to `fragmentSpace`, without adding to backstack.
2. `replace` `fragmentSpace` with `Fragment2`, adding to backstack as `"beginning"`.
3. `add` `Fragment3` to `fragmentSpace2` (which is inside of `Fragment2`), without adding to backstack.
4. `replace` `fragmentSpace2` with `Fragment4`, adding to backstack as `null`.
5. Call `getFragmentManager().popBackStack("beginning", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);` in an attempt to undo all the Transactions, which should bring the user back to seeing only `Fragment1`.

However, the app crashes on step 5 with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090004 (me.MitchT.testfragmenttransactions:id/fragmentSpace2) for fragment Fragment3{7f35cb6 #2 id=0x7f090004}
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:886)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:1645)
...
```

I have found that if I add step 3 to the backstack, step 5 no longer crashes the app and there is no more error. Why?

The problem I have with adding step 3 to the backstack is that I want the user to be able to press the back button after `Fragment3` is added and go back to `Fragment1`. If I add it to the backstack, then when the user presses the back button it removes `Fragment3`, but `Fragment2` is still visible, so they must press the back button *again*. I am trying to avoid that double-back-button behavior.

I did not feel it was necessary to post the code for every single file in the example app on this question, so instead I created a [gist.](https://gist.github.com/MitchTalmadge/1df0da1828ae168e7314)

So I guess my questions are:

1. Why do I get this error?
2. Why don't I get the error after adding step 3 to the backstack?
3. Is there a better way of "going back to the beginning" or going back two fragments at a time?

Thanks!

Comment: The view with id beginning is not found. Just use `popbackstack()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understand. You have a fragment layout which is the container in activity

Activity hosts Fragment1. Then you replace Fragment 1 by Fragment 2 ( added to back stack.

At this stage clicking back button you will have fragment2 popped and you see the activity  which hosts fragment1.

Fragment2 has a framelayout which holds fragment3. Then you have Fragment4 replacing fragment3 which is added to back stack.

Now clicking the button you have  `getFragmentManager().popBackStack("beginning", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`. But there is no view with that id.

Just use `popBackStack()`. Fragment4 --> Fragment2 ( hosting fragment3) --> Fragment1 ( hosted by the activity).

If you want Fragment4 to Activity hosting Fragment1 don't add Fragment4 to the back stack.

Note : In case you want nested fragments you need to use `getChildFragmentManager()`. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html

Also note the discussion in the comments sections and the link posted by op [Is this the right way to clean-up Fragment back stack when leaving a deeply nested stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802141/is-this-the-right-way-to-clean-up-fragment-back-stack-when-leaving-a-deeply-nest)

Comment: In step 2 I add to backstack as "beginning" though: https://gist.github.com/MitchTalmadge/1df0da1828ae168e7314#file-mainactivity-java-L29 Shouldn't it be found from that?

Comment: @MitchTalmadge but you have fragment4 in the stack.

Comment: @MitchTalmadge also note that fragment2 is in backstack and fragment3 and 4 is hosted by fragment 2.

Comment: Thank you, I did a for loop using popBackStack and that solved the issue. I still do not understand how the backstack cannot find "beginning" however. Especially after reading the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802141/is-this-the-right-way-to-clean-up-fragment-back-stack-when-leaving-a-deeply-nest

It was my understanding that popBackStack(String, int) would essentially do popBackStack() until it reached the transaction with the specified tag.

Comment: @MitchTalmadge try the same when you have fragment2 replacing fragment1 it does not. also note its nested fragments. still reading the link that you post

Comment: @MitchTalmadge i tried adding replacing fragment2 with fragment 4. Then the solution in the link you mentioned works like the one you have popBackStack with name. I would also look into the case of nested fragments.

Comment: @MitchTalmadge in case you need nested fragments you should use `getChildFragmentManager()`.  Just try with that keep the same code you had before http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/about/versions/android-4.2.html

Comment: Heck yeah! That fixed it! Thanks so much!! I had no idea about getChildFragmentManager(), that makes a lot more sense to me. Thank you!