# Return to a fragment by using popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

Lets assume that I have a bunch of fragments.

A->B->C->D....->K->L

On Fragment L, I want to return to fragment D directly by popping the fragments between these two. I assume that I need to use popBackStack(String name, int arg1) but I can't seem to understand the information that this method requires from me with the "name" parameter.

Documentation says: "If non-null, this is the name of a previous back state to look for". The name is clearly not the name of my destination fragment (e.g FragmentD). Can you please explain the usage of this method?

Comment: hint: look at the `addToBackStack` method.

Comment: The answer to this question might be helpful with explaining the popBackStack-method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802141/is-this-the-right-way-to-clean-up-fragment-back-stack-when-leaving-a-deeply-nest