# Clear back stack when navigation drawer is opened

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

How can I clear the back stack excluding the home screen when the navigation drawer is opened?

Additional information: I only have 2 activities. I am mostly working with fragments. I have a navigation button in the action bar. When I back-press my activity shows previously unwanted fragments. I want to clear all the fragments when I open the drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is here:

[Is this the right way to clean-up Fragment back stack when leaving a deeply nested stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802141/is-this-the-right-way-to-clean-up-fragment-back-stack-when-leaving-a-deeply-nest)

Essentially, what you want is `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`

Comment: That works like a charm thanks! UPDATE: though its working like i wanted but doesnt really clear all the stack. Sorry, if you dont mind me asking , where exactly do i add this code?

Comment: You'd have to add some code in order to have a clearer idea. Although going by your description, I suppose you want it done in `onBackPressed`.