# How to remove all object in fragment after popBackStack?

Tags: android, fragment, fragment-backstack

I have a problem with fragment when I make an media player app.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sio8.jpg)

I open fragmentB from fragmentA (have addToBackStack) and then back previous fragmentA from fragmentB (using popBackStack). (see more in image). When I popBackStack, all objects and fragmentB has been keep in stack system. Although In fragmentB, onDestroy method is called. So, if I do so again n times, the fragmentB and objects in fragmentB will keep all in stack of system. Finally, when i do again with m times, I got OutOfMemory error.

So, My question is: How to clear all objects and fragmentB after popBackStack?

This is example code i created: https://github.com/sinhpn92/FragmentStackTest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802141/is-this-the-right-way-to-clean-up-fragment-back-stack-when-leaving-a-deeply-nest
Did you check this?

Comment: Duc Nguyen: Yes. I did. You can see my example