# Handling Instance of Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I am working on an E-com module.I have implemented two fragments in an activity.One(HomeFragment) is loading within the activity in container and another(CartFragment) is loading `onClick` of Cart icon placed on toolbar. Now everytime when i am clicking on cart icon same fragment is loading again and again, which is fine i want it in a same way.But now i want no matter how many times i load the same fragment but on pressing back button it should go on home screen.Right now when i am pressing back key it is returning all the loaded fragments.How should i solve this. Please Help.

CODE IN CONTEXT:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeFragment.OnAdd,HomeFragment.OnDel,FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener{

    private  int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        HomeFragment blank = new HomeFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, blank);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        //----------------CART ICON---------------------//
        MenuItem item1=menu.findItem(R.id.cart);
        item1.setIcon(buildCounterDrawable(count, R.mipmap.cart));
        //----------------SPINNER ICON------------------//
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinner_list_item_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.cart) {
            CartFragment myDetailFragment = new CartFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            myDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_main, myDetailFragment);

       fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);


            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //---------------------------INFLATING BADGE------------------------------//

    private Drawable buildCounterDrawable(int count, int backgroundImageId) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.counter_menuitem_layout, null);
        view.setBackgroundResource(backgroundImageId);

        if (count == 0) {
            View counterTextPanel = view.findViewById(R.id.counterValuePanel);
            counterTextPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            textView.setText("" + count);
        }

        view.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActionPerformedAdd(int count1) {
        count++;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionPerformedDel(int count1) {
          if (count>0){
              count--;
              invalidateOptionsMenu();
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {

    }
}
```

**HomeFragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private Button add,del;
    private  int count = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        add=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        del=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.minus);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((OnAdd)getActivity()).onActionPerformedAdd(count);
            }
        });

        del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((OnDel)getActivity()).onActionPerformedDel(count);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public interface OnAdd{
        void onActionPerformedAdd(int count);
    }
    public interface OnDel{
        void onActionPerformedDel(int count);
    }

}
```

**CartFragment**

```
public class CartFragment extends Fragment {


    public CartFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        return view;
    }



}
```

Comment: I dont know [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5984892/1595442) can help you but may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try changing your onBackPressed() implementation to

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1 ){
            while(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1){
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have two fragment containers to acheive this. Just toggle the visibility of the needed fragments!